# Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it

Tags: java, exception, collections, concurrentmodification

I am using a `Collection` (a `HashMap` used indirectly by the JPA, it so happens), but apparently randomly the code throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. What is causing it and how do I fix this problem? By using some synchronization, perhaps?

Here is the full stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Are you merging, updating or deleting an entity? What associations doest this entity have? What about your cascading settings?

Comment: From the stack trace you can see that the Exception happens while iterating through the HashMap. Surely some other thread is modifying the map but the exception occurs in the thread that's iterating.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

This is not a synchronization problem.  This will occur if the underlying collection that is being iterated over is modified by anything other than the Iterator itself.

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry item = it.next();
    map.remove(item.getKey());
}
```

This will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when the `it.hasNext()` is called the second time.

The correct approach would be

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry item = it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Assuming this iterator supports the `remove()` operation.

Comment: Possibly, but it looks as if Hibernate is doing the iterating, which should be implemented reasonably correctly. There could be callback modifying the map, but that is unlikely. The unpredictability points to an actual concurrency problem.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with threading concurrency, it is caused by the backing store of the iterator being modified.  Whether by another thread of not doesn't matter to the iterator.  IMHO it is a poorly named exception since it gives an incorrect impression of the cause.

Comment: I agree however that if it is unpredictable, there is most likely a threading issue which is causing the conditions for this exception to occur.  Which makes it all the more confusing because of the exception name.

Comment: This is correct and a better explanation than the accepted answer, but the accepted answer is a nice fix. ConcurrentHashMap is not subject to CME, even inside an iterator (although the iterator is still designed for single-thread access).

Comment: This solution has no point, because Maps don't have iterator() method. Robin's example would be applicable to e.g. Lists.

Comment: I think the point was still served, but you are correct in that my example was wrong.  It has been fixed.

Comment: I was working on android and it took me like 4 hours to actually find something that pointed out my issue. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 90):

Try using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a plain `HashMap`

Comment: Did that really solve the problem? I am experiencing the same issue but I can most certainly rule out any threading issues.

Comment: Another solution is to create a copy of the map and iterate through that copy instead. Or copy the set of keys and iterate through them, getting the value for each key from the original map.

Comment: It is Hibernate who is iterating through the collection so you cannot simply copy it.

Comment: Instant savior. Going to look into why this worked so well so I don't get more surprises further down the road.

Comment: @CodeBrickie, yes, it somehow does solve the problem that @Robin wrote about. Anyway `map = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);` doesn't solve anything :) So this is not a threading issue, it appears that ConcurrentHashMap is more noob-safe :)

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap can be modified while it is being iterated and it won't throw. The downside is slower performance.

Comment: I guess its not synchronization issue it is problem if modification of same modification while looping same object.

Comment: From ConcurrentHashMap Javadoc
`Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time. `

Answer (score 35):

Modification of a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) while iterating through that `Collection` using an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is *not permitted* by most of the `Collection` classes. The Java library calls an attempt to modify a `Collection` while iterating through it a "concurrent modification". That unfortunately suggests the only possible cause is simultaneous modification by multiple threads, but that is not so. Using only one thread it is possible to create an iterator for the `Collection` (using [`Collection.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()), or an [enhanced `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)), start iterating (using [`Iterator.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()), or equivalently entering the body of the enhanced `for` loop),  modify the `Collection`, then continue iterating.

To help programmers, *some* implementations of those `Collection` classes *attempt* to detect erroneous concurrent modification, and throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if they detect it. However, it is in general not possible and practical to guarantee detection of all concurrent modifications. So erroneous use of the `Collection` does not always result in a thrown `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The documentation of [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) says:

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible...
>
> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception...
>
> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis.

Note that

- the exception **may** be throw, not **must** be thrown
- different threads are not required
- throwing the exception cannot be guaranteed
- throwing the exception is on a best-effort basis
- throwing the exception happens [when the concurrent modification is *detected*, not when it is *caused*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723542/545127)

The documentation of the [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) classes says this:

> The iterators returned [directly or indirectly from this class] are fail-fast: if the [collection] is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the `Iterator` throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

Note again that the behaviour "cannot be guaranteed" and is only "on a best-effort basis".

The documentation of several methods of the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface say this:

> Non-concurrent implementations should override this method and, on a best-effort basis, throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if it is detected that the mapping function modifies this map during computation. Concurrent implementations should override this method and, on a best-effort basis, throw an `IllegalStateException` if it is detected that the mapping function modifies this map during computation and as a result computation would never complete.

Note again that only a "best-effort basis" is required for detection, and a `ConcurrentModificationException` is explicitly suggested only for the non concurrent (non thread-safe) classes.

## Debugging `ConcurrentModificationException`

So, when you see a stack-trace due to a `ConcurrentModificationException`, you can not immediately assume that the cause is unsafe multi-threaded access to a `Collection`. You must [examine the stack-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) to determine which class of `Collection` threw the exception (a method of the class will have directly or indirectly thrown it), and for which `Collection` object. Then you must examine from where that object can be modified.

- The most common cause is modification of the `Collection` within an enhanced `for` loop over the `Collection`. Just because you do not see an `Iterator` object in your source code does not mean there is no `Iterator` there! Fortunately, one of the statements of the faulty `for` loop will usually be in the stack-trace, so tracking down the error is usually easy.
- A trickier case is when your code passes around references to the `Collection` object. Note that *unmodifiable* views of collections (such as produced by [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))) retain a reference to the modifiable collection, so [iteration over an "unmodifiable" collection can throw the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726337/concurrentmodificationexception-in-unmodifiable-collection) (the modification has been done elsewhere). Other *views* of your `Collection`, such as [sub lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)), [`Map` entry sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) and [`Map` key sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) also retain references to the original (modifiable) `Collection`. This can be a problem even for a thread-safe `Collection`, such as [`CopyOnWriteList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527519/copyonwritearraylist-throwing-currentmodificationexception); do not assume that thread-safe (concurrent) collections can never throw the exception.
- Which operations can modify a `Collection` can be unexpected in some cases. For example, [`LinkedHashMap.get()` modifies its collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16180833/545127).
- The hardest cases are when the exception *is* due to concurrent modification by multiple threads.

## Programming to prevent concurrent modification errors

When possible, confine all references to a `Collection` object, so its is easier to prevent concurrent modifications. Make the `Collection` a `private` object or a local variable, and do not return references to the `Collection` or its iterators from methods. It is then much easier to examine *all* the places where the `Collection` can be modified. If the `Collection` is to be used by multiple threads, it is then practical to ensure that the threads access the `Collection` only with appropriate synchonization and locking.

Comment: I wonder why concurrent modification is not allowed in case of a single thread. What problems can occur if a single thread is allowed to do a concurrent modification on a regular hash map ?

Answer (score 16):

In Java 8, you can use lambda expression:

```
map.keySet().removeIf(key -> key condition);
```

`removeIf` is a convenient `default` method in `Collection` which uses `Iterator` internally to iterate over the elements of the calling collection.
The extraction of the removal condition is expressed by allowing the caller to provide a `Predicate<? super E>`.

"I'll perform the iteration for you and test your `Predicate` on each one of the elements in the collection. If an element causes the `test` method of the `Predicate` to return `true`, I'll remove it."

Comment: Beautiful. This should go to the top. Is it O(n) time, O(1) space?

Comment: This is more elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds less like a Java synchronization issue and more like a database locking problem.

I don't know if adding a version to all your persistent classes will sort it out, but that's one way that Hibernate can provide exclusive access to rows in a table.

Could be that isolation level needs to be higher.  If you allow "dirty reads", maybe you need to bump up to serializable.

Comment: I think they meant Hashtable.  It shipped as part of JDK 1.0.  Like Vector, it was written to be thread safe - and slow.  Both have been superseded by non-thread safe alternatives: HashMap and ArrayList.  Pay for what you use.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the selected answer cannot be applied to your context directly before some modification, if you are trying to remove some entries from the map while iterating the map just like me.

I just give my working example here for newbies to save their time:

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap();
//adding some entries to the map
...
int threshold;
//initialize the threshold
...
Iterator it=map.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<Character,Integer> item=(Map.Entry<Character,Integer>)it.next();
    //it.remove() will delete the item from the map
    if((Integer)item.getValue()<threshold){
        it.remove();
    }
```

Comment: The magic is "it.remove()" instead of "map.remove(item.getKey())". Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Try either CopyOnWriteArrayList or CopyOnWriteArraySet depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exception when try to remove x last items from list.
`myList.subList(lastIndex, myList.size()).clear();` was the only solution that worked for me.