# reports java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, jasper-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757970/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-jasperreports)

I have a problem ...
I have this source code in java :

```
HashMap<BigDecimal ,JRBeanCollectionDataSource> MyHasMap = .......
parameters.put("MyHasMap ", MyHasMap );
```

The JRBeanCollectionDataSource has a list of beans.

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(............. , parameters, ..............);
```

In my reports I have this....

REPORT "FATHER":

```
<parameter name="MyHasMap " class="java.util.Map" isForPrompting="false"/>

<band height="25">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="25"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MyHasMap ">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MyHasMap }]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+
"SUBREPORT1.jasper"]]/>
            </subreport>
</band>
```

SUBREPORT 1 :

```
<parameter name="MyHasMap " class="java.util.Map" isForPrompting="false"/>

<group name="G_HOJA" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{X}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="33">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="14" width="535" height="15"/>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalProducciones}.get($F{X})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +
"SUBREPOR2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
```

The field X is a field that I get of a query in the report.

SUBREPORT 2 : I paint the fields of my bean

```
......
....
<textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{FIELD1}]]></textFieldExpression>
...
...
```

When I have one record of field X all its ok, but when the query return me more records ...I have the next exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.next(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:87)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.advanceDataSource(JRFillDataset.java:861)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:779)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1448)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:923)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:561)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I'm use jasperrepots - 3.7.0.
someone has any idea???

Thanks

Comment: why is duplicated? the problem is not the same as in other post