# (JasperReports Struts2)java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

does anyone also has the below exception when develop under Struts2 and JasperReort 4.8.0.
We are using JasperReports 4.8.0 and struts2-jasperreports-plugin 2.3.15 in production.
We occasionally see this ConcurrentModificationException on a few of our reports.
The full stacktrace is following:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.ValueStackDataSource.next(ValueStackDataSource.java:154)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.advanceDataSource(JRFillDataset.java:1379)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1228)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1207)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1549)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:153)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:325)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
com.alven.fun.security.UrlFilter.doFilter(UrlFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757970/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-jasperreports)

Comment: I find the reason know. Thank you all the same.

Comment: It will be better if you post the solution as the answer

Comment: Thank you. I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**
Hi all, I find the reason that I send a session attribute reference as dataSource to jasper. This reference will be changed in real time. So when Jasper try to traverse ArrayList, the value is changed. So the exception will happen.