# Android: Sharing lists between two threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

I'm doing an app in which I have 2 views which extend from SurfaceView, called CanvasView.

I have a left CanvasView, and a right CanvasView. 
Both these CanvasView instantiate a UIThread, which extends from Thread. 
The CanvasView itself is passed into the thread like this:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  uiThread = new UIThread(this);
  uiThread.setRunning(true);
  uiThread.start(); 
}
```

In each CanvasView, onDraw() , I do an access to a list. This list basically consists of a list of things to draw, which are essentially the same on both left and right canvases.

```
for (CharSequence line : lineList) {
... 
..
}
```

Whenever my app needs to draw the items in lineList, it crashes saying 
java.util.ConcurrentModificaitonException.

What is the correct way to "share" the Arraylist lineList between the two threads?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is not thread safe and when multiple threads attempts to modify the same list, it will end up with concurrent modification exception.

Use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Refer the link - [Is there a concurrent List in Java's JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)

Collections.synchronizedList() is an other alternative which will provide the synchronized access to the list.

Comment: Thanks my issue was solved using CopyOnWriteArrayList and Erm, not using so many threads XD

Comment: Hi @lppier, You use CopyOnWriteArrayList  in onDraw. Don't you have performance issue?

Comment: @JasonChueh didn't notice anything, is there an alternative?

Comment: @lppier, I just wondered if you were facing any issue. If there's not, this should be a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` class is not [Thread Safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Use `Collections.synchronizedList()` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the simplified version of for loop

```
for (CharSequence line : lineList) {
    ... 
    ..
}
```

Instead, use the traditional one. However, you have to handle data consistency by yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); i++) {
    CharSequence line = lineList.get(i)
    ..
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry but what is the difference between the two here?

Comment: The first one is a compiler sugar. Since the list is a collection, compiler translates the for loop with iterator. Iterator is the one who throws the exception. However, if you store your data in an array, the exception will not be thrown. Compiler will use the regular for loop if your data is a simple array.