# Why JDK API team does not using lock stripping to implement a Concurrent List?

Tags: java, jvm, java-8

Why JDK API team does not using lock stripping to implement a Concurrent List (like Concurrent Map) ? Java provides ConcurrentSkipListSet and CopyOnWriteArrayList but not a list with lock stripping approach.

Comment: What did they tell you when you asked them?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916414

Comment: Because lock striping doesn't work if you can partition the data structure into FIXED sections (stripes).  And you simply can't do that (efficiently, scalably) with a list that conforms to the `List` API.  Basically, the fact that the `List` API has operations that index the list means you can't create a general purpose concurrent list.

Comment: (Or at least, if it >> is << possible, nobody has achieved it yet ... to my knowledge.)

Comment: The best example of a "concurrent list" that I could find was this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm ... It is concurrent in the sense that it is thread-safe (with weak consistency guarantees) in the face of multiple threads iterating and modifying.  HOWEVER it doesn't implement any index-based operations.  Note also the original author.

Comment: Thanks you guys, yes that answer has required info.

Comment: My first comment should read *"Because lock striping doesn't work if you cannot partition ..."*.  Double negatives are tricky :-)

Comment: @Stephen C: so that “concurrent doubly linked list without index-based operations” basically is a [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html), so it got into the Java API, just with a clearer name. In the end, if something of that author does not make into the Java API, there must be a strong reason for that…