# Java - Add elements to an ArrayList while browsing it

Tags: java

The problem is that I have this method `createNode()` that creates a node in a tree, and then if it's a leave node it adds it into an `ArrayList<Tree> treeLeaves`, and I make the call of this method while browsing the `treeLeaves` ArrayList like this :

```
    Iterator<Tree> iter = treeLeaves.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        iter.next().createNode();
    }
```

Or like this :

```
    For (Tree cursor : treeLeaves) {
        cursor.createNode();
    }
```

But I keep having this exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Even when put the codes below in `snychronized(treeLeaves){}` bloc.
P.S: I don't know if this is usefull or not but; it's an n-Tree.

Comment: I believe there are some other key info you are not showing: Based on what you showed us, you are not changing the the list (`treeLeaves`) when iterating it.  The above code shouldn't cause `ConcurrentModificationException` (at least not from `treeLeaves`)

Comment: @AdrianShum I said below that the `.createNode()` method adds a node, and if it's a leave node it adds it into `treeLeaves`. Is it still not comprehensive ?

Comment: oops, I see what you mean there then.  Coz it does not look that normal so I missed your point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `ArrayList`, you could avoid the iterator by just using an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < treeLeaves.size(); i++) {
    Tree current = treeLeaves.get(i);
    // your code
}
```

As long as the only thing you do is append to the end of the array, and you don't insert in the middle or at the beginning or delete any items, this will work.  `treeLeaves.size()` will be recomputed every time you go through the loop, which means that if you append to the end, the size will be recomputed and `i` will get to the new items.  Yes, using an old-fashioned loop isn't as "cool" as an iterator, but it works.

I don't recommend using this for any kind of `List` other than an `ArrayList`, because in general, `get(i)` will have to start from the beginning of the list and step through each element (unless the runtime optimizes the case where you're using `get(i+1)` after `get(i)`, which wouldn't be too hard, but I don't know whether the implementations do that).  For an `ArrayList`, however, `get(i)` should take constant time.

Comment: Yeah thank you @ajb, in fact it's a mind-trick, once you learn the iterator way. It does'nt make you want to use the "old-fashioned" loop anymore. Anyway, this is helping, so thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

You need A ConcurrentList...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

read [Is there a concurrent List in Java's JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)

Also you can't change a arraylist when browsing it... Instead you can use a buffer in tempoaray memory to edit current list if you like.

Comment: synchronized list won't help.  `ConcurrentModificationException` means more than multi-thread acccess to a collection.

Comment: Okey thank you verry much @Ya Wang, I am going to try it and I'll be intouch

Comment: Indeed this is great I don't have the Exception anymore. Thank you.

Comment: what's happening is actually nothing different from my solution :P  COW actually means it is having a new copy of list when you add to it (while you still iterating the original copy).

Answer (score 1):

This is because in Java, when an Iterator is created, you cannot modify the underlying data structure. The enhanced for loop "for (Tree cursor : treeLeaves))" uses an Iterator.

As Ya stated, "Also you can't change a arraylist when browsing it... Instead you can use a buffer in tempoaray memory to edit current list if you like."

Answer (score 0):

In brief, in most cases, if you change the structure of a collection, all still-open iterators will become invalid.  (Quite some exception including using Concurrent collections, or modification is done through the iterator, or etc.)

Your problem can be demonstrated easily by:

```
List<Node> treeLeaves = new ArrayList<>();

//... add something to treeLeaves

for (leaf :  treeLeaves) {
    treeLeaves.add(new Node());
}
```

For your case, it can be easily solved by creating a new collection to iterate:

```
List<Node> treeLeaves = new ArrayList<>();
//... add something to treeLeaves

List<Node> tempLeaves = new ArrayList<>(treeLeaves);    
for (leaf :  tempLeaves ) {
    treeLeaves.add(new Node());
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have to go as far as the `treeLeaves` ArrayList expands. Using a temporary list doesn't work, as no update is done while browsing.