# Concurrent data structures in java

Tags: java, vector, collections, concurrency

I need a concurrent List, and the first idea that came into my mind is using Vector.
But as far as i know, Vector is not very efficient for example when reading (two threads cannot read from it at the same time).

Is there any existing collection that improves this? (`ConcurrentHashMap` is not a good option because it doesn't allow duplication's).

Comment: answered long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk (CopyOnWriteArrayList)

Comment: thanks @MikhailAntonov !

Comment: my only question is - is it opossible that reading operation (like get(i)) will wait in CopyOnWriteArrayList? for example if another thread in writing at the same time.