# Changing an immutable data structure from two threads

Tags: kotlin, immutability

I use immutable data-structures as much as possible, because it's really easy to work with them. The problem though is when two threads modify the data-structure. In that case, the `synchronized` keyworks helped, but isn't one reason for immutable data-structures, to avoid `synchroinzed`?

What is the more idemoatic way to modify a immutable list from two threads?

```
data class MyEvent(val time: Long, val somethingElse: String)
class EventReceiver {
    private var events = listOf<MyEvent>()

    // called several times a second
    fun addEvent(e: MyEvent) {
        synchronized(this) {
            events += e
        }
    }

    // internal cron-trigger calls this every 10 seconds
    fun purge(olderThan: Long) {
        synchronized(this) {
            events = events.filter { it.time < olderThan }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well immutable means that cannot be modified, which is not the case for your data structure (the `EventReceiver` object), isn't it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6916385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable data structures can not be mutated - it's in the name. That means there are no methods on it that modify its state. If there are, it's not immutable.
Thus, your `EventReceiver` is not immutable and you need to design for data races to make it thread safe.

One of the ways to make data structures thread safe is using locks to guard access to the contested properties, such as using `synchronized` like you're doing here.

Comment: Your right. But the question should target the question, how to handle mutabion of a immutable list from two threads.

Comment: You can't. Like I said, an immutable list can not be mutated.