# How Java streams works when the list it is working is concurrently modified?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have a list with 10 elements and I take  a stream view of it, filter it by age and  collect it in anther list.
And in between someone adds 5 elements to the list.
What will be the behavior of the streams 
will it work with only 10 elements or 15 ??.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: No it will not work as you will get concurrentModificationException as @NicholasK suggested you should try it. and if you don't want this error then you should use concurrenthashmap collection to do the same operation.

Comment: before adding such type of post pls try it. because ppl simple copy and paste theory from doc they will not try it...

Answer (score 1):

Read the "Non-Interference" section in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). In particular:

> Unless the stream source is concurrent, modifying a stream's data source during execution of a stream pipeline can cause exceptions, incorrect answers, or nonconformant behavior.

So the answer to your question is that it depends on the type of list, whether it's concurrent or not, and if it's not, how it handles concurrent operations and *at what point* you make the moddification (before or in the middle of the terminal operation).

Comment: basically it's the shortest path to nightmares - just don't

Comment: This answers my question

Comment: In case of concurrent modifications, it also depends on the JVM and the particular optimization state. E.g. it’s possible that such a broken code fails with an exception in one execution but produces an incorrect result in a subsequent execution with exactly the same input.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) - if you're lucky. From the exception's documentation, the most relevant part is:

> In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

I tried this example code:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
myList.add(3);
Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        myList.add(4);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myList.add(5);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myList.add(6);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myList.add(7);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myList.add(8);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
Thread threadB = new Thread(() -> {
    myList.forEach(i -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
});

threadA.start();
threadB.start();
```

Which results in:

```
1
2
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1252)
    at com.company.Main.lambda$main$2(Main.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Switching out the non-thread-safe `ArrayList` for a synchronized `Vector` results in:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But you can't *rely* on this behavior. The documentation is quite clear that it is undefined, and that makes it likely to change between different implementations or even different versions. Don't do it. Use thread safe containers such as `Vector` and `ConcurrentHashMap`, and use synchronization primitives around them in a way that makes sense for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Or not. If you use `ArrayList` behavior is not defined because it is not thread safe.

Comment: "Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected." The behavior is defined by the iterator, not the collection.

Comment: I know. I just want to say that not all implementation is thread safe.

Comment: what if the list for e.g. is of type [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)?

Comment: Actually even Vector didn't work when I tried. Just added the code which I tried

Comment: @BandiKishore yes, while `Vector` is thread safe, iterating it requires explicit synchronization (as stated in its documentation), which rules out concurrent modifications. Generally, you have to check a collection class’ documentation regarding the iteration behavior, e.g. `ArrayList`’s documentation clearly says that it is fail-fast, but “on a best-effort basis”, so it’s still not guaranteed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried with both [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and both of them gave me [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

However [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) works fine.

```
    int valueLength = 10;
    List<Integer> myList = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valueLength; i++) {
        myList.add(i);
    }
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            myList.stream().filter(i -> {
                try {
                    if (i % 3 == 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (int i = valueLength; i > 0; i--) {
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                    myList.remove(i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
```