# exception when using Thread on loop

Tags: java

i get an exception when i run my Main Class :[exception on Thread's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lNa0.png)

i using run method, and it look like this :

```
    @Override
public synchronized void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
    Student studentThread = new Student();
    Inlay inlayThread = new Inlay();
    studentThread.setId(counter);
    inlayThread.setInlayId(randomNum);
    Course courseThread = new Course();
    courseThread.setInlayD(inlayThread);
    courseThread.setStudentD(studentThread);
    this.arrCourse.add(courseThread);
    System.out.println(courseThread.toString());
    counter++;
}
```

and my Main :

```
    Course c = new Course();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<200;i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(c);
        t.start();
    }
    c.toString();
```

what is tihs exception say ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add items to an ArrayList at the same time using different threads. You will have to use a concurrent data structure (or use different lists, them merge them to together.)

You can find more about concurrent lists here: [Is there a concurrent List in Java's JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

You try to add the items to (I guess) a common implementation `ArrayList` or `List` which is not thread safe and causes the [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) which is thrown upon modifying (add/delete) a structure on which is not optimized to do so.

I recommend using the [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) wrapper:

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

```
List<Course> arrCourse = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: now it work ! but why ? this code say to 2 thread to not using the same pleace (like index 1 ) at the same time ?

Comment: See the documentation of the [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). The point is the exception is rather thrown than risk a non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: i thinkg my english no soo good to understand your link.. i'll try get help from my friends, thanks alot !