# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while looping through arrayList

Tags: java, android

Following is my code piece:

```
ArrayList<Contact> contactList = presenter.getContactList();
for (Contact contact : contactList) {
    if (null != contact) {
        String name = contact.getVehicleNumber();
        final ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList = contact.getVehicles();
        if (vehicleList != null && vehicleList.size() > 0) {
            name = vehicleList.get(0).getVehicleNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. 
I have gone through other answers for similar questions but I am not doing any modifications to the original list by adding or removing items. Strange thing is it doesn't happen always.
Will this `Exception` occur if `presenter.getContactList()` is modified by some other thread while this code piece is executed ?

Stack trace,

```
12-23 12:08:35.961 24843 25128 E AndroidRuntime: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
12-23 12:08:35.961 24843 25128 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:62)
```

Comment: `vehicleList.at(0)` generates a compiler error on my machine. Also, what line generates the `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: ```vehicleList.at(0)``` should be ```vehicleList.get(0)``` which I wrote by mistake while copying from my project. The ```Exception``` happens on ```line 2``` on the for loop line.

Comment: "For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it" - from javadocs. So yes, it can't be modified by some other thread.

Comment: How it works `vehicleList.length()`? Should use `vehicleList.size()` instead

Comment: Can you print the stackTrace?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman My bad. Edited now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni Added stack trace.

Comment: Try using `ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>(presenter.getContactList());` instead

Comment: Have you used an iterator instead of the for loop and was able to reproduce this error

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni Since I am not modifying the list, I didn't used it. How it will be useful anyway ?

Comment: Is this an actual copy paste of your code? Are you using multiple threads? Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker No it's not. I modified the original code to make it presentable. The code pieces are from a SDK so can't share it. Yes multiple threads are used.

Comment: Multiple threads are accessing the same data structures? Are you expecting it wont?

Comment: Can you try by making a deep copy instead of a shallow copy?  I think its making a shallow copy and that is the reason why this problem is originating.

Comment: If you are using multiple threads, check out concurrent lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk . It's possible that multiple threads try to access the arrayList at the same time.