# Synchronized block over a list in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list in which items are iterated and processed. These should be added to another list after being processed. This is legacy code and I have to implement parallel processing.

```
class demo{

    public void function1(){

        List<TestPojo> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        oldList.parallelStream.forEach(item->
        function2(newList,item)
        ); 

    }

    public void function2(List<TestPojo> newList, Item item){

        TestPojo testPojo = formPojo(item);

        synchronized(newList){
            newList.add(testPojo);
        }

    }



}
```

Owing to certain legacy conditions, I cannot change the function signatures. Will this cause an issue? Am I breaking any rules by not using a synchronized list?

Comment: The code seems alright to me. Not sure what the question is tho.

Comment: @Amongalen, I wanted to know if I'm breaking any rules by not using a synchronized list.

Comment: are you worried about race conditions or concurrent operations? why not try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk ? Unless you disclose *why* you had to use `synchronized`, your actual code could have been reduced to `List<TestPojo> newList = oldList.parallelStream()
                .map(item -> formPojo(item))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Naman, thanks for the reply. I understand the solutions provided in the link. I was wondering if doing a manual synchronization on a list that has not been declared as a synchronized list still help given that function2  is called within parallel streams.

Comment: the synchronized will prevent real trouble, but all parallel-processing will serialize at this point, only "TestPojo testPojo = formPojo(item);" will be processed parallel as result. to avoid this you could use a approach like  "foreach().collect(Collector ...". Initializing the ArrayList with a expected size should improve performance (avoid resizing the internal structures while add)