# ConcurrentModificationException coming for CopyOnWriteArrayList as well

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, copyonwritearraylist

I am using the following code to create a CopyOnWriteArrayList, modify the elements residing in it and then printing the elements. I am not able to understand why I am getting ConcurrentModificationException when I am using CopyOnWriteArrayList.

```
public class Solution {
    public static int main() {
          CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> arrList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

          //fill the array list;
          List<Integer> sublist = arrList.sublist(startIndex, endIndex);
          arrList.removeAll(sublist);
          arrList.addAll(sublist); //here is where the ConcurrentModificationException comes and I dont understand why

          //iterate and print the elements of the list.
    }      
}
```

Comment: I suspect it is because `sublist` gives you a list that is *backed by the original list*.

Comment: [copyonwritearraylist-throwing-currentmodificationexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527519/copyonwritearraylist-throwing-currentmodificationexception)