# Can using foreach of CopyOnWriteArrayList cause ConcurrentModificationException in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, copyonwritearraylist

I look to java 11 implementation of `.foreach` method in `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

```
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Object x : getArray()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E e = (E) x;
        action.accept(e);
    }
}
```

I see that it just loops the array without any locks.
Can `add()` or `remove()` performed concurrently with `foreach` give a `ConcurrentModificationException`?
In contrast to `iterator()`, `foreach` seems to avoid using the copy of original array on write and it uses no locks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can using `foreach` of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` cause `ConcurrentModificationException` in java?

No.  You can see that from the code that it doesn't throw  `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Object x : getArray()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E e = (E) x;
        action.accept(e);
    }
}
```

Note that `getArray()` call is not copying the array.  It is declared like this:

```
private transient volatile Object[] array;

final Object[] getArray() {
    return array;
}
```

(Since `array` is `volatile`, no lock is needed to ensure that `getArray()` returns the current version of the array.)

---

> Can `add()` or `remove()` performed concurrently with `foreach` give a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

A call to those methods will cause a new backing array to be created with the update.  This is done holding a lock on the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, and then the array is replaced.

Meanwhile, the `foreach()` call will loop over the **old** array as if nothing happened.

---

> In contrast to `iterator()`, foreach seems to avoid using the copy of original array on write and it uses no locks.

Actually, `iterator()` behaves the same way as `foreach`.  It calls `getArray()` to get the current backing array.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new COWIterator<E>(getArray(), 0);
}
```

And if you look at the `COWIterator` class, it doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException` either.

---

Note that this is all specified in the javadocs.

1. The javadocs for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` state:

   > "... the iterator is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`."
2. The javadocs for `foreach` (in `Iterable`) state:

   > "The default implementation behaves as if:"
   >
   > for (T t : this)
   > action.accept(t);

   which is using the iterator provided by `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`; see 1.

---

However, there is a small gotcha.  A sublist of a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, and it *can* produce a `ConcurrentModificationException`; see [CopyOnWriteArrayList throwing CurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527519)

Comment: Good point about the gotcha - and the point goes even more generally, as according to the Javadoc for List.subList(), this kind of behaviour is "semantically undefined" :) Another gotcha to be aware of is that calls to get() on the sublist will not be lock-free, whereas the raison d'être of CopyOnWriteArrayList is to provide lock-free reads. Put another way, if you have a use case for calling subList() on a CopyOnWriteArrayList, you should possibly be using a different flavour of list...