# ConcurrentModificationException and HashSet.iterator()

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have a for loop like

```
      for (int neighbour : neighbours) {
```

Where I may modify `neighbours` within the loop. Found that thats the cause of `ConcurrentModificationException`. And read from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189527/292291

> Hence if you want to modify the list (or any collection in general),
>   **use iterator**, because then it is aware of the modifications and hence
>   those will be handled properly.

So I tried:

```
neighboursItr = neighbours.iterator();
while (neighboursItr.hasNext()) {
  // try disconnecting vertices
  neighbour = neighboursItr.next();
```

But that doesnt fix the problem. Why?

Comment: Could you post some more code? What do you do with `neighbour`?

Comment: Are you still getting same exception?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you calling `neightbours.remove(neighbour)`? In that case, that is the problem. You need to call `neightboursItr.remove()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a new `HashSet` with desired state? I mean you can iterate through the `neighbours` and add to the `newNeighbours` whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may only modify the collection **using methods of the iterator** while iterating on the collection. So you may call `neighboursItr.remove()`, but you may not add an element to the collection using `neighbours.add()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify collection while iterating. The only exception is using `iterator.remove()` method (if it is supported by target collection).

The reason is that this is how iterator works. It has to know how to jump to the next element of the collection. If collection is being changed after iterator creation it cannot do this and throws exception.

There are several solutions for this problem. For example if you want to add elements to existing collection during iteration you can create yet another collection where you store new elements and then add all these elements after your iteration is finished.