# Throwing ConcurrentModificationException if we add elements in ArrayList at the end while iterating

Tags: java, collections

I am iterating elements of ArrayList using Iteratot.While iterating I am adding an element into the ArrayList at the end. But getting an error : ConcurrentModificationException.

If I change ArrayList to Set and tried to add elements in set at the end during iteration no error is throwing

Test.java

```
class Test {
  public static void main() {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(20);
    al.add(30);
    al.add(40);

    Iterator<Integer> it = marks.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      int value = it.next();
      if (value == 40) al.add(50);
    }
  }
}
```

Test2.java

```
class Test2 {
  public static void main() {
    Set<Integer> marks = new HashSet<>();
    marks.add(20);
    marks.add(30);
    marks.add(40);

    Iterator<Integer> it = marks.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      int value = it.next();
      if (value == 40) marks.add(50);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't actually compile. Please provide a [mcve]... while it doesn't take a huge amount of work to change it, it's better for you to do it once than each reader to have to do it.

Comment: Oh, and I get the same error with `HashSet` as with `ArrayList`...

Comment: Not getting it with `HashSet` is a fluke, due to the specific implementation of `HashSet` that you're using.

Comment: @911DidBush: The OP is comparing an `int`, not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a better solution, but this one is working as well. A second list is used and then added to the original one, after the loop has finished.

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int stepSize = 10;

        al.add(20);
        al.add(30);
        al.add(40);

        Iterator<Integer> it = al.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            int value = it.next();
            if (value == al.get(al.size() - 1)){
                toAdd.add(value + stepSize);
            }
        }

        // Add all elements
        al.addAll(toAdd);

        // Print
        al.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

In case you only want to append *one* element based on the last value, as in your example, you could also wait until the loop is finished (if you still need it) and try to add it like this:

```
al.add(al.get(al.size() - 1) + stepSize);
```

**Output**

```
20
30
40
50
```

Answer (score 1):

It is mere fluke that you don't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` with `HashSet`. The reason for that fluke is that you happen to add the element on the *last* iteration of the loop.

This is far from guaranteed to happen, because `HashSet` has no ordering guarantees. Try adding or removing some more elements from the list, and you'll find that eventually be able to get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, because the `40` won't be the last element in the list.

The simplest way to reproduce this is to work with just a single element (since then the ordering of the `HashSet` is known):

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
hashSet.add(1);
for (int i : hashSet) {
    hashSet.add(2);
}
```

This won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
for (int i : list) {
    list.add(2);
}
```

This *will* throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

As to the reason why you don't get the exception when adding to a `HashSet` on the last iteration,
look at the source code for the iterator returned by [`HashSet.iterator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator):

```
abstract class HashIterator {
    // ...

    public final boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, the `hasNext()` value is precomputed, based on `next`; this is set a bit lower down in the code:

```
    final Node<K,V> nextNode() {
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        Node<K,V> e = next;
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if ((next = (current = e).next) == null && (t = table) != null) {
            do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
                                           // ^ Here
        }
        return e;
    }
```

So, the value of `hasNext` is determined when the previous element of the iteration is determined.

Since your code is:

```
Iterator it = marks.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  int value = it.next();
   if (value == 40)
     marks.add(50);
}
```

the `hasNext()` is called after the loop iteration in which the element is added; but `next` was set to null when `it.next()` was called - before the call to `add` - and so `hasNext()` will return false, and the loop exits without `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

On the other hand, the [iterator of `ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#840) uses the size of the underlying list to determine the return value of `hasNext()`:

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
            // ^ current position of the iterator
            //           ^ current size of the list
    }
```

So this value is "live" with respect to increasing (or decreasing) the size of the underlying list. So, `hasNext()` would return true after adding the value; and so `next()` is called. But the very first thing that `next()` does is to check for comodification:

```
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        // ...
```

And thus the change is detected, and a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Note that you *wouldn't* get a `ConcurrentModificationException` with `ArrayList` if you modified it on the last iteration, if you were to add *and remove* an element (or, rather, to add and remove equal numbers of elements, so that the list's size is the same afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Yes , This is expected for normal List.

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for concurrent activity on List.

For example , [click here](http://www.journaldev.com/1289/copyonwritearraylist-java)

Comment: I think the somewhat-implicit question is why it *doesn't* occur for `HashSet`.

Comment: Same kind of problem may occur in HashSet as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562548/concurrentmodificationexception-and-hashset-iterator