# Throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

So this is a function from my snake game code. Basically I was initially doing a for to go though the `LinkedList<Point>` that is the snake but since it was throwing the exception I thought changing it using iterators would help.
Apparently not. 
How can I fix this?

```
public void drawSnake(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    Iterator<Point> iterator = snake.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Point p =iterator.next();
        g.fillRect(p.x * BOX_WIDTH, p.y * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code throwing the exception? Doesn't seem likely at all to me.

Comment: Agree with @kviiri , there's no modification in this example, so this should not throw any Exception.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189466/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception

Comment: @kviiri I do udnerstand what you are saying since there are no (at least visible) modifications to the snake in that function but the error points towards it :/

Comment: @Asura14, post the stack trace of the exception, it might have something of interest.

Comment: @kviiri actually I found the problem is solved. I'll answer my own question as soon as StackOverflow allows me to. Thank you for the help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this exception occurs when collection has been modified while iterating over it.
Most likely that means that `snake` is being modified in another thread. This code, considered independently, should not throw CME, so this is the only possible explanation remaining.

Try looking for all usages of `snake` variable and analyze whether they can be done together with the code you posted.

Another very, very unlike possibility is that `g.fillRect()` method deletes `p` from the `snake` collection. This can possible if you overrided the method, for example.