# remove an object from a List

Tags: java, list, iterator

let's say we have a a Pencil class which has two attributes like this:

```
public class Pencil {
    String color;
    int length;

    public Pencil(String c, int sh, int l) {
        this.color = c;
        this.length = l;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

then we put 4 Pencil's object into a Box:

```
public class Box {

    ArrayList<Pencil> list;
    public Box() {
        list = new ArrayList<Pencil>();
        list.add(new Pencil("blue", 5, 10));
        list.add(new Pencil("black", 5, 10));
        list.add(new Pencil("brown", 5, 10));
        list.add(new Pencil("orange", 5, 10));
    }
}
```

and then we want to remove one of these objects from the list based of the value of `color`:

```
public class TestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box b = new Box();
        ArrayList box = b.list;        
        Iterator it = box.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Pencil p = (Pencil) it.next();
            if (p.getColor() == "black") {
                box.remove(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

seems pretty straightforward, but i'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell what I'm missing here

Comment: There's a few issues here...and to ward off any potential dupe-closers, it doesn't feel like it fits neatly into the "compare strings" or "concurrent modification" questions.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189466/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception

Comment: @chrylis:  The question being posed in the linked duplicate is of a different nature than the one being posed here.  I don't feel that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @Makoto: Disagree. It's about the CME coming from using `box.remove()` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @chrylis Take another look; the question asks why do you get a CME in one instance but not another.  This one asks about the CME in one context alone (and there are other issues).  It's not a clean duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two issues.

The first issue - why you're getting `ConcurrentModificationException` - is because you're using the **list** to remove elements, not the **iterator**.

You must use `it.remove()` to remove the element you're currently on.

Next, you're comparing strings with `==` - this isn't guaranteed to work at all.  You should be using `.equals` instead.

Reverse the order you compare them against so you don't run a chance of getting a `NullPointerException` there, too.

Here's what the block looks like, revisited.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box b = new Box();
    ArrayList<Pencil> box = b.list;
    for(Iterator<Pencil> it = box.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Pencil p = it.next();
        if ("black".equals(p.getColor())) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `it.remove()` instead of `box.remove(p)`.