# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in android(GLThread 23204)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrentmodification

Trying to add objects using a Map object, I'm getting a concurrent modification exception on the 4th line of this function:

```
public void reloadResources() {
        taskQueue.add(new GLResorceTask() {    //ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GLResorceTask> taskQueue
            public void perform(GLView gl) {
                for(Entry<Resource, GLResourceLoader> entry : reloadMap.entrySet()) {
                    Resource res = entry.getKey();
                    if(res != null)
                        entry.getValue().load(res);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189786/1320616

Answer (score 2):

you can try

> ```
> public void reloadResources() {
>     taskQueue.add(new GLResorceTask() {    //ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GLResorceTask> taskQueue
>         public void perform(GLView gl) { 
>         CopyOnWriteArrayList list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(reloadMap);
>             for(Entry<Resource, GLResourceLoader> entry : list.entrySet()) {
>                 Resource res = entry.getKey();
>                 if(res != null)
>                     entry.getValue().load(res);
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```