# How to avoid "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" error in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to calculate Standerd Deviation,mean avarage etc. I am trying to write below code. but it thows exception  **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**.I am tryng to fix it but faild.

**My code:**

```
package statistic;

import java.util.*;

public class StanderDeviation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("step 1:create a list of 10 numbers :");

        List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
        numbers.add(23.0);
        numbers.add(92.0);
        numbers.add(46.0);
        numbers.add(55.0);
        numbers.add(63.0);
        numbers.add(94.0);
        numbers.add(77.0);
        numbers.add(38.0);
        numbers.add(84.0);
        numbers.add(26.0);
        System.out.println("\n " +numbers);

        System.out.println("step 2: average  of 10 numbers : ");

        double sum = 0;
        for(double number : numbers)
        {
            sum= sum +number;
        }
        double average = sum / numbers.size();
        System.out.println(sum + " / " + numbers.size() + " = " + average);

        System.out.println("\nstep 3: difference between each number numbers and average :");

        List<Double>listOfDifferences = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(double number : numbers)
        {
            double difference = number - average ;
            listOfDifferences.add(difference);
            System.out.printf("%2.2f", difference);
            System.out.printf(" "); 
        }


         System.out.println("\n\nstep 4: Square of above calculate difference :");

        List<Double> squares = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(double difference : listOfDifferences)
        {
            double square = difference * difference ;
            listOfDifferences.add(difference);
            squares.add(square);
            System.out.printf("%4.2f", square);
            System.out.printf(" "); 
        }
        System.out.println("\nstep 5:sum of Square   calculate above :");

        sum = 0;
        for(double number : squares)
        {
            sum += number ; 
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("step 6: divide sum of Square by totle (numbers)-1 :");

        double result = sum / (numbers.size()-1);
        System.out.printf("%4.2f", result);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\nstep 7: Stander Deviation is the Square root of obove result :");

        double StanderDeviation = Math.sqrt(result);
        System.out.printf("%4.2f", StanderDeviation);
    }
}
```

**And here is the exeption error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at statistic.StanderDeviation.main(StanderDeviation.java:50)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't modify the lists you are iterating over by adding or deleting items in them.

Comment: sorry i am not understand. i am new in java. can you explain it.

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189786/3288182) helps

Comment: In a for loop like `for(double difference : listOfDifferences){...}` you cannot add or delete items in the `listOfDifferences` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies within this loop:

```
for(double difference : listOfDifferences)
{
    double square = difference * difference ;
    listOfDifferences.add(difference);
    squares.add(square);
    System.out.printf("%4.2f", square);
    System.out.printf(" "); 
}
```

You are trying to add something to the list you're currently iterating over!

Just remove the line `listOfDifferences.add(difference);`!

It will not affect your calculation of standard deviation. (And it doesn't really make sense to add the `difference` you just received from the list `listOfDifferences` back to the same list again!)

Answer (score 1):

You could create other `List` structure(***if it's really needed in your case***) and add elements to it like:

```
   List<Double> changed = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for(double difference : listOfDifferences)
        {
            double square = difference * difference ;
//            listOfDifferences.add(difference);
            squares.add(square);
            changed.add(difference);
            System.out.printf("%4.2f", square);
            System.out.printf(" ");
        }
```

It's not possible modify `Collection` which you iterate on.

[ConcurrentModificationException Oracle doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)