# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in iterating over TreeSet

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ConcurrentModificationException and a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap)

I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at Types$AdjList.makeConnected(Types.java:281)
at Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

while executing the following code

```
public void makeConnected() {
        TreeSet<Node> exploredNodes = new TreeSet<Node>();
        TreeSet<Node> unexploredNodes = new TreeSet<Node>();
for (Node n : unexploredNodes) {
        ...
        exploredNodes.add(n);
        unexploredNodes.remove(n);
        ...
}
```

I am not using the iterator like in HashMap but need to use a Set that may grow or reduce based on some condition.
I will accept and give points to all answers. Look forward to how to replies on how to solve this problem of ConcurrentModificationException
Thanks,
Somnath

Comment: @assylias: Ok, I see there is iterator for TreeSet

Comment: @assylias: But there is no iterator.remove() for TreeSet. Do you know how to remove from a TreeSet using iterator?

Comment: All iterators have a remove method. Check the second piece of code in the first answer in the link above and replace the map by your set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop internally uses iterators and you are not removing the elements using the iterator. Hence, the problem. Use iterator's remove method as below:

```
for (Iterator iterator = exploredNodes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     Node n = (Node) iterator.next();
     unexploredNodes.add(n);         
     iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: I am not being able to use the iterator.hasNext(). It is popping a message:The method hasNext() is undefined for the type HTMLDocument.Iterator