# How to deal with ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, for-loop, runnable, concurrentmodification

I am getting the a ConcurrentModificationException from my cooldown timer. I use a thread to reduce the values every second like this:

```
public class CoolDownTimer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String s : playerCooldowns.keySet()) {
            playerCooldowns.put(s, playerCooldowns.get(s) - 20);
            if (playerCooldowns.get(s) <= 0) {
                playerCooldowns.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So every second it should reduce every players cooldown by 20, but the problem is that I a getting the CME every couple hours while running the program, especially when lots of people are online. How do I make it so that if it is still modifying the list, it will wait until the current operation is done and create a sort of modification queue? Thanks! Here is the stack trace:

```
2012-06-18 20:59:05 [WARNING] Task of 'SurvivorsClasses' generated an exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:839)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:874)
at me.zachoooo.survivorclasses.CoolDownManager$CoolDownTimer.run(CoolDownManager.java:13)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:126)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:533)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:459)
```

Line 13 is the start of the for loop...

Comment: You should not modify your HashMap concurrently, if you want concurrent access try using ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify collections when using a foreach loop.

You *can* however iterate over the `Map.entrySet()` and do everything you need:

```
public void run() {
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> i = playerCooldowns.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = i.next();
        entry.setValue(entry.getValue() - 20); // update via the Map.Entry
        if (entry.getValue() <= 0) {
            i.remove(); // remove via the iterator
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i.remove(); // remove via the iterator , is the line that does the trick

Answer (score 1):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown while you try to modify the contents of your `Collection`, at the same time while `Iterating` through it.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492814/java/java/Why-does-Iterator-sometime-throw) for more discussion on it.

The reason why sometimes it might work out for you is clearly mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if 
the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way 
except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a 
ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the 
iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic 
behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally 
speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized 
concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a 
best-effort basis.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unlike Array`, `Collections` are **Checked only** during the **Compilation time**, **NOT** during the **run time**, thats the reason you **cannot modify the Collection like put() or remove()** in the loop.