# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while accessing hashmap

Tags: java, exception, collections, hashmap

Why is the below exception happening?

```
2012-08-28 11:41:59,183 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/TFO].[tfo]] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-9) Servlet.service() for servlet tfo threw exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793) [:1.6.0_24]
            at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:834) [:1.6.0_24]
            at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:832) [:1.6.0_24]
            at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromMap(JSONObject.java:1082) [:]
            at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:173) [:]
            at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2552) [:]
```

Comment: It would be difficult to tell without knowing what you tried to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException and a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap)

Comment: I just accessed map from session and removed one object again i set it into session

Comment: Go through Below Link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How have you tried to remove the object (key, value) in the map? If you used the [for-each Construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) and tried to remove it the Exception will be thrown even if your code executes in a single-threaded environment.

If you have iterated it like this:

```
for(Entry<String, Object> entry : session.entrySet()) {
   if (condition) {
      // throws a ConcurrentModificationException
      session.remove(entry.getKey());
   }
}
```

Then you should change it to that:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = session.entrySet().iteration;
while (it.hasNext) {
   Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next(); 
   if (condition) {
      it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
   }
}
```

Similar discussed in the question [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)