# issue with hashmap getting concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I am getting the below error while using map and performing some remove.How to avoid this ?

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:834)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:832)
```

```
   Map<FormField, Object> ItemMap = domainItem.getValues();         
   for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> ValMap : ItemMap.entrySet()) {         
       List<Field> groupIdList = Mapper.getGroupId(groupFieldId);           
       for (Field field : groupIdList) {
           ItemMap.put(new FormField(field), domainItem.getDomainItemLinkId());
       }
       ItemMap.remove(ValMap.getKey());
   }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:

Use Iterator and `ConcurrentHashMap` to avoid this scenario

Following won't throw exception

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "a");
    map.put(2, "b");
    map.put(3, "c");
    map.put(4, "d");
    for (Iterator<Integer> keys = map.keySet().iterator(); keys.hasNext();) {
        Integer key = keys.next();
        String val = map.get(key);
        map.remove(key);
    }
```

or use another map while iterating and at the end copy it to source

for example:

```
    Map<Integer, String> dummy = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "a");
    map.put(2, "b");
    map.put(3, "c");
    map.put(4, "d");
    dummy.putAll(map);
    for (Iterator<Integer> keys = dummy.keySet().iterator(); keys.hasNext();) {
        Integer key = keys.next();
        String val = map.get(key);
        map.remove(key);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: how to avoid this i need to add the data also.

Comment: ,please explain how can i use a iterator in my above snippet

Comment: can also show the another map nd copy snippet example because in my case map is already available to me

Answer (score 0):

A Map is sorted by the keys in the key-value pairs.  When you add or remove elements from the Map while you are iterating through them, the program essentially loses track of "where" in the Map it is.

To get around this, try making a separate, temporary transfer Map.  There is also a class called `Iterator` which might suit your needs.

Comment: ,please explain how can i use a iterator in my above snippet

Comment: Jigar Joshi explains it with code samples in an answer above. =)

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid this issue is to iterate over a copy.

```
for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> ValMap : 
     new HashMap<FormField, Object>(ItemMap).entrySet()) {
```

Comment: if i create a copy then i can use   for (Field field : groupIdList) {
                        ItemMap.put(new FormField(field),
                                domainItem.getDomainItemLinkId());
                    }
                    ItemMap.remove(ValMap.getKey());

Comment: Its not possible to say from the code you have given as your interaction is very complicated.  I would move this code into the class of `domainItem` so you can see all the dependencies.

Comment: Map<FormField, Object> ItemMap = domainItem.getValues();         
   for (Map.Entry<FormField, Object> ValMap : 
     new HashMap<FormField, Object>(ItemMap).entrySet()) {         
       List<Field> groupIdList = Mapper.getGroupId(groupFieldId);           
       for (Field field : groupIdList) {
           ItemMap.put(new FormField(field), domainItem.getDomainItemLinkId());
       }
       ItemMap.remove(ValMap.getKey());
   }

Comment: You need to include the code for all the methods called in case there are side effects, which is why suggest you put all the code in one place. The reason I am concerned is that half the loop doesn't appear to need to be there so there must be something going on which I cannot see. ;)

Comment: can u please explain with some other solution,iterator or so.Seems not to be working out in my case

Comment: Its impossible to say what you should do without know what you are trying to achieve. It doesn't make any sense as it is.

Comment: i want to loop over map and add some data to it,removing the previous one.So i m doing as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

can be done without a copy of the map, execute this example and take a look at the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println("creating map ...");

    Map<String, String> dummyMap = new HashMap<>();
    while (dummyMap.size() < 10)
    { dummyMap.put(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()), String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt())); }


    System.out.println("start, map size: " + dummyMap.size() + ", keys=" + dummyMap.keySet());


    System.out.print("going to remove: ");
    for (Iterator<String> keys = dummyMap.keySet().iterator(); keys.hasNext(); )
    {
      final String key = keys.next();

      // delete map entries per random
      if(new Random().nextInt(3)>1)
      {
        System.out.print(key+" ");
        keys.remove();
      }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println("done, map size: " + dummyMap.size() + ", keys=" + dummyMap.keySet());
  }
```

and take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap).

HTH,