# Java ConcurrentModificationException when using list.remove()

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I've got a method called `removeSup` which is supposed to remove an object `Supplement` from a list of supplements.
this is the code for the method:

```
private static void removeSup(Supplement supToRemove, List<Supplement> listToRemoveFrom) {
   Iterator<Supplement> iterator = listToRemoveFrom.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    if(iterator.next().equals(supToRemove)){
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
}
```

there is a class called `magazine` which defines the list of supplements.

```
public class Magazine {
  private List<Supplement> supList;
  public List<Supplement> getSupList() {
        return this.supList;
    }
  public void setSupList(List<Supplement> supList) {


      this.supList = supList;
        }
public Magazine(Double cost, String _name){
        this.supList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.weekCost = cost;
        this.name = _name;
    }
    }
```

the class `supplement` has the following constructor

```
public Supplement(String _name, Double _price, String _magName ){
        this.name=_name;
        this.price=_price;
        this.magName = _magName;
    }
```

in the main class `client` there is a search that the user can do to remove a certain Supplement

```
private static void searchSup(){
   System.out.println("Search for Supplement");
        String search = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Supplement sup : magazine.getSupList()) {
            if (!sup.getSupName().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
         //do something
        }
        else{
              removeSup(sup,magazine.getSupList());
        }
    }
```

}
the main method in the client class is as follows:

```
 private Magazine magazine;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                magazine = new Magazine(3.0, "pop");
                List<Supplement> startList = new ArrayList<>();
            startList.add(new Supplement("Nat Geo", 3.0,"pop"));
            startList.add(new Supplement("Discovery", 5.0,"pop"));
            startList.add(new Supplement("Health", 6.3,"pop"));
            startList.add(new Supplement("IT", 8.3,"pop"));
            magazine.setSupList(startList);
            searchSup();
        }
```

When I run this program and type any of the added supplements, i get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at Client.searchSup(Client.java:131)
    at Client.searchSup(Client.java:140)
    at Client.main(Client.java:588)
```

is it the for loop i am using to search giving me an error? if so how would i go about fixing this?

Comment: did you read the javadoc for ConcurrentModificationException?  also, did you search SO for similar problems?

Comment: Instead of traversing the list again in `removeSup` with a new iterator, iterate with an explicit iterator in `searchSup` and use that iterator's `remove` in `searchSup`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException and a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap)

Comment: @user2357112 has the best answer IMO

Comment: @user2357112 i tried doing that and getting the same error. `else{
              magazine.getSupList().remove(sup);
        } like that right?

Comment: @Pindo: No, that's the list's `remove`. You need the iterator's `remove`.

Comment: @user2357112 could you post a sample code of how i would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the search i was doing was not working with what i wanted to do so i created a method which returns an integer of the Supplement in the list.

```
private static int indexOfSup(List<Supplement> supSearchList, String nameOfSup) {
        for (Supplement sup : supSearchList) {
            if (sup.getSupName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfSup)) {
                return supSearchList.indexOf(sup);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

i then use this integer to remove from the list.
a simple `List.Remove(index)` worked fine

Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: You're really doing a lot of work that Java could be doing for you.  Look up the `Collection` and `List` interfaces, specifically their `remove()` methods as well as how to override `equals()` for an object.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't modify a `Collection` while iterating over it.  It's fine to modify elements, but you really shouldn't remove something from a `Collection` while iterating.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.  Also, the Javadoc for `ConcurrentModificationException` may be helpful.

You might try returning a new list with the `Supplement` removed:

```
 private static List<Supplement> removeSup(Supplement supToRemove, List<Supplement> listToRemoveFrom) {
    List<Supplement> filteredSupplements = new ArrayList<Supplement>();
    for(Supplement supplement : listToRemoveFrom) {
       if(!suppplement.equals(supToRemove)){
           filteredSupplements.add(supplement);
       }

    }

    return filteredSupplements;
}
```

Comment: thanks. is there any way i can go around removing an element from the list?

Comment: The `Collection` interface has a `remove()` method but you'll need to read the Javadoc for each collection that implements it.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the "magazine" is local var in the method of main, not accessible to searchSup.Fix it like
    private void searchSup(Magazine magazine)
    {
        //...
    }
and more details if you can provide, the codes in Line 131 and 140 will be helpful.