# Removing element in ArrayList using INDEX causing java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code is causing

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

I am not sure how to solve the error please help !

```
ArrayList strList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cmd.split(" ")));

        if (strList.get(0).equals("LIST")) {

        }

        if (strList.get(0).equals("DEPEND")) {
            strList.remove(0); // getting error at this point 
            cm.createComponent(strList);

        }
```

**Full Method** The outer loop is not related to the List

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ComponentManager cm = new ComponentManager();

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cmdList.txt"));
    for (String cmd : lines) {
        ArrayList strList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cmd.split(" ")));

        if (strList.get(0).equals("LIST")) {

        }

        if (strList.get(0).equals("DEPEND")) {
            strList.remove(0);
            cm.createComponent(strList);

        }

        if (strList.get(0).equals("INSTALL")) {

        }

        if (strList.get(0).equals("REMOVE")) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to user iterator ,

Comment: There's no iteration here.

Comment: there is no loop i just need to remove the 1st element

Comment: Show the full method.

Comment: give try removing first element by iterator

Comment: Can you show us full stack trace? It is like there is another problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison But since the list is wrapped in an `ArrayList`, the OP shouldn't be seeing `UnsupportedOperationException` either. Definitely a case of missing details from the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that wrapper. Oh well...

Comment: Are you sure that not somewhere there is a `lines.remove(0);` or list assignment. If you are working in the NetBeans IDE, you can run FindBugs by Source -> Inspect.

Comment: You're checking `strList.get(0)` after changing the `strList` this can lead to some kind of other problems. Maybe it'd be more suitable to use switch on string?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a different ArrayList and perform remove operation there or put up an iterator on the arrayList and remove using the iterator.

Find a couple of potential solutions to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825933/java-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-list-remove).