# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException - go through the set and delet

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Pls help me with this problem. I have Graph represent by Structure HashMap> graf; and i need to  go throught that hashmap and set and  remove some edges. How can i do that ?  code give me this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)


      public String vratCestu() {
            String vrat = "";
            for(String s: this.graf.keySet()){
                if (this.graf.get(s).size() != 0)

                    for(String k : this.graf.get(s)){
                            this.graf.get(s).remove(k);
                            this.graf.get(k).remove(s);
                            vrat += k + "; ";

                    }
                }
                return vrat;
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException and a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enhanced for loop `for(String s: this.graf.keySet())`, use an `Iterator`
You cannot modify the collection while iterating over it with the use of enhanced for loop.

Comment: i am beginner in java pls can u write me an exaple how can i do it ?

Comment: Refer the link that @peter-lawrey has suggested in his comment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify your *HashSet* **directly** while iterating over.