# optorsim throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrentmodification, thread-exceptions

this programme (optoesim ) is throwing a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` at the line for `stats.put("jobTimesWithQueue", new LinkedHashMap(_jobTimesWithQueue));`.

This is an opensource program and I did'n change anything. Can someone please explain to me what it means, what causes it, and how can I avoid it.

```
Exception in thread ConcurrentModificationException

java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)** 
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:744)

at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.SimpleComputingElement.getStatistics(SimpleComputingElement.java:164)
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.GridDataThread.run(GridDataThread.java:95)
```

```
public Statistics getStatistics() {
    Map stats = new HashMap();
      // After remove see the result here.
    OptorSimParameters params = OptorSimParameters.getInstance();
    float _usage = _time.getTimeMillis() - _startRunning == 0 ? 0 : 100 *_workingTime/(_time.getTimeMillis() - _startRunning);
    stats.put("usage",  new Float(_usage));
    stats.put("remoteReads",  new Long(_remoteReads));
    stats.put("localReads",  new Long(_localReads));
    if( params.outputStatistics() ==3) {

        stats.put("jobTimes",  new LinkedHashMap( _jobTimes));
        stats.put("jobTimesWithQueue", new LinkedHashMap(_jobTimesWithQueue));
        stats.put("jobFiles",  new LinkedHashMap(_jobFiles));
        stats.put("numberOfJobs", new Integer(_jobsCompleted));
        stats.put("workerNodes",  new Integer(_workerNodes));
        stats.put("status",  new Boolean(_active));
        stats.put("queueLength",  new Integer(_inputJobHandler.getQueueSize()));
        stats.put("runnableStatus",  new Boolean(_runnable));
    }
    stats.put("totalJobTime",  new Float(_totalJobTime/(float)1000));


    long meanJobTime = 0;
    if (_jobsCompleted!=0)
       meanJobTime = _workingTime/_jobsCompleted;
      /////////////////////////////////////////
    stats.put("meanJobTime",  new Long(meanJobTime));

    return new Statistics(this, stats);
}
**Edit:**
```

**I would to show you all the detail of the erreur**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-72" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:744)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.SimpleComputingElement.getStatistics(SimpleComputingElement.java:174)
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.SiteDataThread.run(SiteDataThread.java:112)
```

**when i click on the first linkedhashMap**

```
    final LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> nextNode() {
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> e = next;
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        current = e;
        next = e.after;
        return e;
    }
```

**second linkedhasMap**

```
 final class LinkedEntryIterator extends LinkedHashIterator
    implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public final Map.Entry<K,V> next() { return nextNode(); }
}
```

**and the erreur is in the 3 rd line**
**3 rd linkedhashMap**

```
final class LinkedEntryIterator extends LinkedHashIterator
    implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public final Map.Entry<K,V> next() { return nextNode(); }
}
```

**the erreur is in the first line**
**hashmap**

```
  for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, evict);
```

**linkedhashMap**

```
 public LinkedHashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    super();
    accessOrder = false;
    putMapEntries(m, false);
}
```

**the erreur is in the line**

```
     putMapEntries(m, false);
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.SimpleComputingElement.getStatistics(SimpleComputingElement.java:174)
```

**this is all the code of simpleComputing Elelement**

```
package org.edg.data.replication.optorsim;
```

**/**
 * The ComputingElement runs a thread which executes the GridJobs
 * given to it through its {@link JobHandler}. For each file required,
 * the ComputingElement calls *getBestFile()*, which returns
 * the location of the best replica of the file according to the
 * chosen optimisation algorithm, which may or may not have performed
 * replication. The ComputingElement reads the file from this location
 * and processes it. The time to process the file is calculated as the
 * time specified in the parameters file divided by the number of worker
 * nodes in the ComputingElement.
 *

* Each ComputingElement can currently run only one job at a time.
 * Information on the time taken for each job can be found in the 
 * statistics output at the end of the simulation if statistics level 3
 * is selected in the parameters file, or from the job time histograms
 * if the GUI is used.
 *

* Copyright (c) 2002 CERN, ITC-irst, PPARC, on behalf of the EU DataGrid.
 * For license conditions see LICENSE file or
 * http://www.edg.org/license.html
 *

* @since JDK1.4
 */**

```
public class SimpleComputingElement implements ComputingElement {

private static int _LastCEId = 0;

private GridSite _site; 
private String _ceName;  
private boolean _imAlive;
private boolean _paused = false;
private int _CEId;
private long _workingTime = 0;
private long _startRunning;
private long _totalJobTime = 0;
private Map _jobTimes = new LinkedHashMap();
private Map _jobTimesWithQueue = new LinkedHashMap();
private Map _jobFiles = new LinkedHashMap();

private int _jobsCompleted = 0;

protected JobHandler _inputJobHandler;
protected boolean _runnable = false;
protected boolean _active=false;
protected long _remoteReads = 0;
protected long _localReads = 0;
protected int _workerNodes = 0;
protected float _workerCapacity = 0;
protected GridTime _time;

public SimpleComputingElement( GridSite site,  int workerNodes, float capacity) {

    OptorSimParameters params = OptorSimParameters.getInstance();

    _time = GridTimeFactory.getGridTime();
    _site = site;
    _workerNodes = workerNodes;
    _workerCapacity = capacity;
    _CEId = ++_LastCEId;
    _ceName = "CE"+_CEId+"@"+_site;
    _inputJobHandler = new JobHandler( params.getMaxQueueSize());
    _imAlive = true;
    _site.registerCE( this);
    _startRunning = _time.getTimeMillis();
}

/**
 * Return a more meaningful name.
 * @return the CE's name
 */
public String toString() {
    return _ceName;
}

/**
 * Check whether this CE is active (processing jobs) or idle.
 */
public boolean active() {
    return _active;
}

/**
 * Check whether this CE is still running or has been shut down.
 */
public boolean imAlive() {
      return _imAlive;
}

/**
 * A method to return the input sandbox for this computing element.
 */
public JobHandler getJobHandler() {
    return _inputJobHandler;
}

/**
 * Method to get the site that this CE is on.
 * @return The site this CE is on.
 */
public GridSite getSite() {
    return _site;
}


/**
 * Method to give the name of this CE.
 * @return The name of this CE.
 */
public String getCeName() {
    return _ceName;
}

public int getWorkerNodes() {
    return _workerNodes;
}

/**
 * Method to check against our ID 
 */
public boolean iAm( int id) {
    return _CEId == id;
}

/**
 * Method to collate and return information relevant 
 * to this CE as a {@link Statistics} object.
 * @return The statistics of this CE
 */



public Statistics getStatistics() {
    Map stats = new HashMap();




    OptorSimParameters params = OptorSimParameters.getInstance();
    float _usage = _time.getTimeMillis() - _startRunning == 0 ? 0 : 100 *_workingTime/(_time.getTimeMillis() - _startRunning);
    stats.put("usage",  new Float(_usage));
    stats.put("remoteReads",  new Long(_remoteReads));
    stats.put("localReads",  new Long(_localReads));
    if( params.outputStatistics() ==3) {
                    /*  LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();




        stats.put("jobTimes",  new LinkedHashMap( _jobTimes));
        stats.put("jobTimesWithQueue", new LinkedHashMap(_jobTimesWithQueue));
        stats.put("jobFiles",  new LinkedHashMap(_jobFiles));


        stats.put("numberOfJobs", new Integer(_jobsCompleted));
        stats.put("workerNodes",  new Integer(_workerNodes));
        stats.put("status",  new Boolean(_active));
        stats.put("queueLength",  new Integer(_inputJobHandler.getQueueSize()));
        stats.put("runnableStatus",  new Boolean(_runnable));
    }
    stats.put("totalJobTime",  new Float(_totalJobTime/(float)1000));


    long meanJobTime = 0;
    if (_jobsCompleted!=0)
       meanJobTime = _workingTime/_jobsCompleted;
      /////////////////////////////////////////
    stats.put("meanJobTime",  new Long(meanJobTime));

    return new Statistics(this, stats);
}

/**
 * When running, the ComputingElement processes all the jobs
 * submitted to it through the JobHandler, sleeping while the
 * JobHandler is empty. It is notified to shut down by the 
 * ResourceBroker.
 */
public void run() {

    // Boost our priority
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    Double execTime;
    OptorSimParameters params = OptorSimParameters.getInstance();

    _runnable = true;

    // to keep thread running
    for( GridJob job=null; job != null || _imAlive; ) {

        _active=false;
        job=_inputJobHandler.get();  // This potentially blocks

        // We might get a null job from JobHandler, if so, skip any further activity
        if( job == null)
        continue;

        job.started();

        OptorSimOut.println(_ceName+"> starting to process "+job+" (queue length now "+
                   _inputJobHandler.getQueueSize()+")");
        _active=true;       

        // Install our optimiser
        Optimisable replicaOptimiser = OptimiserFactory.getOptimisable( _site);

        AccessPatternGenerator accessPatternGenerator 
        = AccessPatternGeneratorFactory.getAPGenerator(job);

        String[] logicalfilenames = new String[1];

        List filesAccessed  = new LinkedList();     

        for( String lfn = accessPatternGenerator.getNextFile();
         lfn != null; 
         lfn = accessPatternGenerator.getNextFile()) {

            filesAccessed.add(lfn);

            // Pack the logical file name into the expected structure:      
            logicalfilenames[0] = lfn;
            float[] fileFractions = new float[1];
            fileFractions[0] = (float)1.0;

                // Use optimiser to locate best replica of this file
            DataFile[] files = replicaOptimiser.getBestFile(logicalfilenames, 
                                            fileFractions);
            if( files.length != 1) {
                System.out.println( "ASSERT FAILED: CE, getBestFile return array with wrong number of entries: "+  files.length  +" != 1");
                continue; // skip to next file
            }

            if(files[0] == null) {
                System.out.println( _ceName + "> ERROR getBestFile returned"+
                    " null for "+logicalfilenames[0]);
                continue; // skip to next file
            }

            StorageElement fileSE = files[0].se();
            GridSite fileSite = fileSE.getGridSite();

            // Special case.  If file is remote, then simulate the remoteIO, unPin and move on to next file.
            if( _site != fileSite) {
                simulateRemoteIO( files[0], fileFractions[0]);

                // log this as an access on the close SE (if it exists!)
                if(_site.hasSEs())
                    _site.getCloseSE().accessFile(files[0]);

                if(_workerNodes != 0) {
                    execTime = new Double((job.getLatency() + job.getLinearFactor()*files[0].size())/(_workerNodes*_workerCapacity));
                    _time.gtSleep(execTime.longValue());
                }
                files[0].releasePin();
                _remoteReads++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                fileSE.accessFile(files[0]);
                _localReads++;
            }

            // process the file
            if(_workerNodes != 0) {
                execTime = new Double((job.getLatency() + job.getLinearFactor()*files[0].size())/(_workerNodes*_workerCapacity));
//              System.out.println(this.toString()+"> processing file...");
                _time.gtSleep(execTime.longValue());
            }

            files[0].releasePin();

            //A while loop the ce enters when paused by gui
            while(_paused){
                _time.gtWait(this);
            }

        } // for each datafile in job

        // statistics logging
        long duration = _time.getTimeMillis() - job.timeStarted();
        long durationWithQueue = _time.getTimeMillis() - job.timeScheduled();
        if( duration < 0) {
            OptorSimOut.println("BUG> Duration < 0!!");
        }
        _totalJobTime += durationWithQueue;
        _workingTime += duration;
        _jobsCompleted++;


        if( params.outputStatistics() == 3 || params.useGui()) {
            _jobTimes.put(job.toString(), new Long(duration));
            _jobTimesWithQueue.put(job.toString(), new Long(durationWithQueue));
            _jobFiles.put( job.toString(), filesAccessed);
        }

    } // while there are jobs left to run        
    _runnable = false;
} // run


/**
 * A routine used by the CE to simulate remote IO. The GridContainer's copy() method is
 * used to block the equivalent amount of time.
 */
protected void simulateRemoteIO( DataFile remoteFile, float fraction) 
{
    GridContainer gc = GridContainer.getInstance();
    gc.copy( remoteFile, _site, fraction);
}


/**
 * GUI calls this method to pause the ComputingElement
 * threads when pause button is pressed.
 */
public void pauseCE() {
    _paused = true;
}

/**
 * GUI calls this method to unpause the ComputingElement
 * threads when continue button is pressed.
 */
public void unpauseCE() {
    _paused = false;
    _time.gtNotify(this);
}

/**
 * The ResourceBroker calls this method when it has
 * distributed all the jobs to shut down the ComputingElement
 * threads.
 */
public void shutDownCE(){
    _imAlive = false;
}
```

}

```
at org.edg.data.replication.optorsim.SiteDataThread.run(SiteDataThread.java:112)
```

**the erreur is in the line**

```
 st = ce.getStatistics();






{
              //get the statistics object for this comp. element
              ce = site.getCE();
              st = ce.getStatistics();

              //sample mean job time
              Object r1 = st.getStatistic("meanJobTime");
              String stat1 = r1.toString();
              int stat1Int = Integer.parseInt(stat1);
              seriesSMJTVTime.add(timeSecs, stat1Int);

              //sample job times
              Object r2 = st.getStatistic("jobTimes");
              Map m = (Map)r2;
              int pairs = m.size();
              //if (number of previous key-value pairs != pairs)
              //    instantiate new histarray and fill with job time values
              if (prevNoOfPairs!=pairs)
              {
                 histarray = new double[pairs];
                 int i=0;
                 prevNoOfPairs++;
                 Set keySet = m.keySet();
                 Iterator iter = keySet.iterator();
                 while (iter.hasNext())
                 {
                    Object key = iter.next();
                    Object value = m.get(key);
                    String duration = value.toString();
                    float jobTime = Float.parseFloat(duration);
                    histarray[i] = jobTime;
                    i++;
                 }
              }

              //sample usage
              Object r3 = st.getStatistic("usage");
              String stat3 = r3.toString();
              float coUsage = Float.parseFloat(stat3);
              /* if (range values identical for last three readings)
               *    remove intermediate statistic
               */
              if (coUsage==prevCoUsage&&coUsage==prevPrevCoUsage)
              {
                 int itemCount = seriesSSEUVTime.getItemCount();
                 if (itemCount>2)
                    seriesSSEUVTime.remove(itemCount-1);
              }
              prevPrevCoUsage = prevCoUsage;
              prevCoUsage = coUsage;
              seriesSCEUVTime.add(timeSecs, coUsage);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Is `jobTimes` a field?  (It's not declared in the method.)  If it is, and another thread is modifying it, then that *could* be the cause.  I can't tell from what information is provided here, though.

Comment: I don't khnow but this is stats map when i  run the programme [remoteReads=0, queueLength=200, runnableStatus=true, localReads=32, jobTimes={jpsijob_16=890085, incmuonjob_24=712508}, jobTimesWithQueue={jpsijob_16=890085,.................

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap) (I don't know how to mark a duplicate despite trying to find out in the help)

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException is say that someone has change an item, Which is not the current thread in the time the current thread used in the itme..

So some other thread might iterate over the map.
This probably one object or singleton object because of this line : `OptorSimParameters.getInstance();` that used in general with Singelton design patter.

So that mean the same object changed from 2 places.. From the code you showed and another code part.

If this is open source it possible that this never worked,Or this is a bug you found.. You don't really have what to do with this except maybe to find who call the `OptorSimParameters.getInstance();` and try to understand who else call this method and change or use this map

Hope that make sense

EDIT:

This exception happen when someone like this is happeninig

```
Iterator<Point> iter = points.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
Point p = iter.next();

//Antoher loop inside this one that will just iterate the itmes
Iterator<Point> iter2 = points.iterator();
while (iter2.hasNext()) {
    Point p = iter2.next();
    if (p.equals(pointWeWantToRemove)) {
        iter2.remove();
    }
}

iter.remove();
```

This case above just doing loop inside loop.. Which the outer loop remove items one by one and the inner one will remove specific Point.
The Exce[tion will be thrown in this case because the iterators runs on the same list and remove items for each other..
Once the iterator created `points.iterator()` It will save the init size of the collection and after that he his checking:

```
if (initSize != collection.size()) { 
     throw new ConcurrentModificationException ();
}
```

So in case you created somehow 2 iterators that change the same collection at the same time this thing will happen... You showed one part of the code but if you can find the other iterator we need to think how to avoid this thing. If the other method that used the collection just reading it you can create a clone before reading it, And iterate over the clone of the Collection and it will solve your problem

Hope that make sense

Comment: but what can I add to avoid this exception and where ? I think that the exception is in the map stats.

Comment: You can try to put synchronize on the method signature.. You can try. I am not sure exactly.. Can you add another code part that using this map? If this is a jar you are using or Third party jar you can't do anything.. Except changing the classes but this is not something that i would suggest to do

Comment: I put synchronize  function like this but the exception appear again    */
 public Statistics getStatistics() {
  Map stats = new HashMap();
                   Iterator it = stats.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext())
   {
      Entry item = (Entry) it.next();
      it.remove();
   }

Comment: Try to see who calls this getStatistics(). Someone that call this one is just itertaing on the list before and after..
I will edit my post and give you an example

Comment: thank you very much @Aviad ,I have added other parts of the code ,I hope that helps you to find where is the problem

Comment: Ithink taht I find where is the probleme:

Comment: I think that this part of code make this problem:if( params.outputStatistics() == 3 || params.useGui()) {
            _jobTimes.put(job.toString(), new Long(duration));
            _jobTimesWithQueue.put(job.toString(), new Long(durationWithQueue));
            _jobFiles.put( job.toString(), filesAccessed);
        }

Comment: and the exception appears in those lines:   stats.put("jobTimes",  new LinkedHashMap( _jobTimes));
        stats.put("jobTimesWithQueue", new LinkedHashMap(_jobTimesWithQueue)); 
        stats.put("jobFiles",  new LinkedHashMap(_jobFiles)); and i add all the code ,look at :this is all the code of simpleComputing Elelement,can you tell me what I can add to avoid it pleasssssssss

Comment: If stat is global variable, Where does it defined?