# How Concurrent modification exception is handled internally by CopyOnWriteArrayList/ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrentmodification, copyonwritearraylist

I want to understand internally how concurrent modification exception is handled in concurrent collections like `ConcurrentHashMap` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

There are so many blogs available in internet which suggest to use these two data structures to avoid concurrent modification exception. But nothing explains , how this exception is internally handled by concurrent collection.

Can someone give more insights on this? I need some detailed explanation.

Comment: Note that the most common source of `ConcurrentModificationException` exceptions is *not* concurrency! The most common situation is where you are iterating over and modifying a collection at the same time *within a single thread*.

Comment: There are currently 514 questions tagged [tag:concurrentmodification]. Are you sure one of those doesn't already answer your question?

Comment: Yes . Thats why I raised this question. There is no single page reference

Comment: That's not a good reason to create a new question, though. What we normally do is to pick an existing question and improve the answers. If the answers aren't good enough, you can offer a bounty on the question or add a new answer.

Comment: @DanielPryden the OP question is why CopyOnWriteArrayList and ConcurrentHashMap prevent the CME from being thrown. Your linked answer doesn't address that question. I would imagine an answer does exist though.

Comment: @JohnVint: From JavaUser's comment about looking for a "single page reference" I don't think the intent of the question is to understand the technical reasons why `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ConcurrentHashMap` *don't* raise `ConcurrentModificationException`: indeed, `ArrayList` and `HashMap` **need to go out of their way to throw it**! You could easily have a version of `ArrayList` that doesn't throw CME by simply removing all the code that throws it. But that would be **wrong** because CME isn't a problem to avoid, it's a safeguard to tell you that there is **already** a bug somewhere else.

Comment: You may be right that his intention was a one-stop-shop for answers (which isn't possible). I am only addressing what the question is asking. If there is a better answer that does answer this technical question, then I am all for it.

Answer (score 4):

The literal answer to your question is not very interesting. `ConcurrentHashMap` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList` don't throw `ConcurrentModificationException` because they don't include code to throw it.

It's not like `ConcurrentModificationException` is some low-level intrinsic thing. `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, among other collection classes, throw `ConcurrentModificationException` to **help you**. They have to include **extra code** to try to detect concurrent modifications, and extra code to throw an exception. `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when one of those classes **detect that there is a bug somewhere** that is causing an unsafe modification to your collection.

Classes that support safe concurrent modification don't throw `ConcurrentModificationException` because they don't need to.

If you're trying to debug a `ConcurrentModificationException`, there are plenty of other questions that help answer that:

- [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636)
- [Why doesn't this code throw a ConcurrentModificationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723458)

Answer (score 2):

This will, right now, answer how CopyOnWriteArrayList avoids the need for a ConcurrentModificationException.

When you modify the collection the CopyOnWriteArrayList does two things

1. It prevents other threads from modifying the collection via locking
2. Copies all the elements in the current CopyOnWriteArrayList into a new array and then assigns that new array to the class's array instance

So how does that prevent a CME? A CME in standard collections will only be thrown as a result of iterating. The exception gets thrown if, while iterating over the collection, an add or remove is executed on the same collection instance.

The CopyOnWriteArrayList's iterator assigns the current array as a final field ***snapshot*** of the collection and uses that for iteration. If another thread (or even the same thread) tries to add to the CopyOnWriteArrayList then updates will be applied to a new copy and not the ***snapshot*** one we are currently iterating.

For instance, we know the add method looks like

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        int len = elements.length;
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
        newElements[len] = e;
        setArray(newElements);
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Notice the thread local newElements assignment being made, when that is completed it will set to the class instance `volatile` array.

Then comes the iterator, it's defined as

```
static final class COWIterator<E> implements ListIterator<E> {
    /** Snapshot of the array */
    private final Object[] snapshot;
    /** Index of element to be returned by subsequent call to next.  */
    private int cursor;
```

So when iterating, we are reading whatever was the array prior to any modifications, and since no other thread can modify the snapshot we are looking at a ConcurrentModificationException cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `add()` method definition of `ArrayList` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

**ArrayList:**

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

**CopyOnWriteArrayList:**

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        int len = elements.length;
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
        newElements[len] = e;
        setArray(newElements);
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

From the above code, it is clear that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` takes lock before modifying the map. Here I have just posted the code of the `add` method. If you look on the code of `remove()` / `addAll()` or any `method which modifies` the `List` `structurally` you can see that it takes lock before modifying the collection. Also ArrayList's iterator's method such as `next()/remove()` check for modification but for CopyOnWriteArrayList's iterator's method does not check for the modification. For example :

ArrayList iterator next() method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
```

CopyOnWriteArrayList iterator next() method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        if (! hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return (E) snapshot[cursor++];
    }
```

Comment: how modification count is handled in this scenario? . Is there any specific change on modCount implementation?

Comment: Neither of these code snippets show how `ConcurrentModificationException` is avoided. In the case of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, it's because the internal `Iterator` implementation keeps a reference to the *same* underlying `elements` array throughout the course of iterating, so it doesn't "see" any modifications after that point.

Comment: @JavaUser: `modCount` is how `ArrayList` detects unexpected concurrent modifications, which causes it to raise `ConcurrentModificationException`. As the Javadoc says: "Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs."

Comment: @ Daniel , can you please consolidate and write your views by answer ? . This will helps the readers and get the complete picture.

Comment: @JavaUser I have edited my answer, please take a look. It may help you. Thanks.