# ConcurrentModificationException in HashMap<Object,DateTime>

Tags: java, android, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I have the following code:

```
 Iterator<ggItem> iter = ggItemTimestampMap.keySet().iterator();
 ggItem gg;
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
        gg = iter.next();
        if (DateTime.now().isAfter(ggItemTimestampMap.get(gg).plusSeconds(10))) {
             Log.v("ggItem 10 second limit:", gg.toString());
             //If it hasn't been seen 10 seconds after its last timestamp. Remove it from the ArrayList and remove it from the ggItemTimeStampMap HashMap.
             ggItemTimestampMap.remove(gg); //TODO probable problem causer.
             removeggItemFromList(gg);
         }
 }
```

I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` error on the `iter.next();` call and am uncertain why?

I realize you cannot both access a hashmap of object keys and timestamp values and modify it at the same time, but doesn't the iterator counteract that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can change HashMap to [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Secondary you may have try to synchronize `iter` on class or of object.

```
synchronized(this) // if not in static context 
{
    // synchronized body
}

synchronized(iter)
{
    // synchronized body
}
```

or use in method declaration

```
public synchronized void add(int value){
     this.count += value;
}
```

---

And this problem was explained :

```
// @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
   Entry item = it.next();
   map.remove(item.getKey());
}
```

Correct way :

```
// @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap
   Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext())
   {
      Entry item = it.next();
      it.remove(item);
   }
```

For future troubles you need to know what the [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) means :

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

Answer (score 1):

> I get a concurrentModificationException error on the iter.next();

It's because you are iterating and removing from the same list at the same time. Since you are using an `Iterator`, to remove the item call

```
iter.remove();
```

From the documentation

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   the iterator

Comment: Wouldn't that remove it from the iterator and not the hashmap?

Comment: *Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator*

Comment: Sorry hadn't seen that edit. Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Will accept when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
iter.remove()
```

which removes element from the underlying collection, not from the iterator.

Actually, iterator is just a stateful pointer to the collection, which keeps *internal state*, e.g. link to a currently traversed element. Removing an element, invoking method on iterator provides *separation of concerns* and correct behaviour of the iterator, after element is removed.