# Iterator provided by the Hibernate Interceptor post flush method throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have extended the `EmptyInterceptor` provided by hibernate to perform some logic on post flush. The overwritten post flush method is provided with an iterator. When I tried to iterate, I received `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Below is my code snippet,

```
@Override
public void postFlush(Iterator entities) throws CallbackException
{
    while (entities.hasNext())
    {
        Object entity;

        try
        {
            entity = entities.next();
        }
        catch(ConcurrentModificationException e)
        {
            // I get concurrent modification exception while iterating.

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception,

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:922)
>       at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:950)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.LazyIterator.next(LazyIterator.java:51)
>       at com.mycompany.MyInterceptor.postFlush(MyInterceptor.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postPostFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:401)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1130)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1580)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)

From [Hibernate Forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=966619&view=next) we can understand that the iterator passed to the postFlush() method is not thread safe causing ConcurrentModificationException.

Suggestions and solution to avoid the exception is appreciated.

Comment: Are you removing objects from the HashMap somewhere?

Comment: No I am just calling next() of the `org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.LazyIterator` provided by the method and it is throwing the exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copying iterator into a list via org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils before iterating worked for me :

```
 @Override
 public void preFlush(Iterator entities) {
    List list= IteratorUtils.toList(entities); 
    for(Object o : list){...}

 }
```

However i can't explain why it is working when using IteratorUtils...

Comment: It is a good idea. Did you used this approach to solve the same problem? or is it a common approach that you are proposing? Because this seems to be an issue with the hibernate.

Comment: Yes I used it to solve the same problem. After reflection i think that this 'trick' is working because IteratorUtils traverses the Iteraror fast enough to avoid a concurrent modification while traversing it. But it might still occur I think, so i would advise to catch the ConcurrentModificationException  and retry to copy it until it works... not very sexy though...Or maybe apache internally handles ConcurrentModificationException. I agree that this is a hibernate issue.

Comment: I checked apache  IteratorUtils.toList code and it does not handle ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked for me. As you said it is still a mystery why Apache util don't throws concurrent modification exception.

Answer (score 0):

If it's synchronization issue try using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a plain HashMap

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap) answer i think it might help

Comment: Problem is I don't initialize the hashmap. It is provided by the hibernate listener class on Flush.

Answer (score 0):

Manually copy it in a `List`

```
    @Override
        public void postFlush(Iterator entities) {
            super.postFlush(entities);
            List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
            while (entities.hasNext()) {
                objects.add(entities.next());
            }
.
.
.
```

now you can use `objects` list

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of IteratorUtils.toList, it just does:

```
    List list = new ArrayList(estimatedSize);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        list.add(iterator.next());
    }
```

which isn't any faster than doing it that way, except... perhaps by allocating the list with an estimated size of 10, it is faster because it isn't necessarily having to re-allocate...