# Java: ConcurrentModificationException when iterating over hashmap?

Tags: java

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap) here. However, I do not understand how to extract the value pair from the iterator such that I can put it into a conditional expression to decide whether the key-value pair should be removed.

My original code is as follow, which throws this `ConcurrentModificationException`at runtime:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Order> o: orderIDHashMap.entrySet()) {

    if(o.getValue().getOrderQuantity() == 0) {
        orderIDHashMap.remove(o.getKey());
    }
}
```

I tried to switch it to:

```
    Iterator orderIDHashMap_iterator = orderIDHashMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while(orderIDHashMap_iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Order> pair = (Entry<String, Order>) orderIDHashMap_iterator.next();
        if(pair.getValue().getOrderQuantity() ==0 ) {
            orderIDHashMap_iterator.remove();
        }
    }   
}
```

**Question**: Is my code above correct in implementing iterator to remove object `Order` when `Order quantity == 0` condition is met?  If it is wrong, can someone provide me an answer or a more efficient / elegant way to code this up .

Thanks.

Comment: it is correct but why not check it yourself ? With an unit test for example ?  Besides, you should avoid raw types : type your iterator such as `Iterator<Entry<String, Order>>`  to avoid casts.

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing. In the topic, you talk about some exception. The exception is irrelevant for the question. And as @davidxxx said, [you should not use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Elegancy is not part of the scope of Stack Overflow. When you have a working version, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go for this question.