# Synchronize multiple threads to edit a Hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I want to let a single thread wait for another one to finish writing on a Hashmap but I always get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, eventhough I synchronized the method.

Here is my Code:

```
HashMap<Page, Integer> prebuffer = new HashMap<Page, Integer>();
Map<Page,Integer> buffer = Collections.synchronizedMap(prebuffer);

private synchronized void bufferContaining(int pageid) {
    synchronized (buffer) {
        if (buffer.size() > 1) {
            for (Map.Entry<Page, Integer> entry : buffer.entrySet()) {
                Page page = entry.getKey();
                int taIds = entry.getValue();
                if (page.pid == pageid) {
                    buffer.remove(page, new Integer(taIds));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to the `synchronize` but to the fact that you are removing elements from the collection in which you are iterating, the `buffer` map.

You have few approaches to follow:

- Remember the items to delete, and delete them afterwards
- Use iterator to move and directly remove from the map

Answer (score 0):

This is not a synchronization problem. This will occur if the underlying collection that is being iterated over is modified by anything other than the Iterator itself.

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
   Entry item = it.next();
   map.remove(item.getKey());
}
```

This will throw a ConcurrentModificationException when the it.hasNext() is called the second time.

Question is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/concurrentmodificationexception-and-a-hashmap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)