# Why don't all methods that concurrently modify a shared object need the synchronized modifier?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I would like to understand when to add the `synchronized` modifier to a method that **modifies** a shared object and when not.

I wrote a modified version of the *bouncing balls* game. Each ball (I called it "stone") is a `thread`. To manage the `repaint` process, I keep an `HashSet` of stones and several methods process this set:

- when I add a new stone (if the user presses the Fire button on the GUI);
- when I kill one or more stones (if the user clicks the stones on the `panel`);
- when one of the killer stones (a special "bad" kind of stones) touches any of the normal "good" stones and kills them;
- and finally, when the `paintComponent()` method is called.

Well, I thought the all of the methods that process those things must be declared `synchronized`. But I made some attempts and I found that:

- in some cases the `synchronized` modifier is needed (if I remove it, I get an exception, OK that's what I expected);
- in some other cases I removed the `synchronized` modifier and **I never got any exception**, even running the program more and more, creating and killing tons of killer stones and/or good stones.

I googled a lot but I have read that the `synchronized` modifier is *always needed* when a method accesses a shared object and it isn't needed only if the object is *immutable*.
But then I can't understand why I can remove the `synchronized` modifier from some of those methods **without getting exceptions**.

Now I attach the `StoneSet` class, which is where all those methods are defined.
This class is a *singleton*: only one instance of it is created and shared by almost all other objects in the application.
I cleaned the class from all the unnecessary code and wrote many comments to help readers understand the class and (I hope) tell me what is happening.
I apologize for the long attachment (more than 100 lines).

```
package rollingstones;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

class StoneSet {

    private final HashSet<Stone> set = new HashSet<>(64);       // this is the set
    private AreaGrafica areaGrafica;                            // this is the JPanel

    void setAreaGrafica(AreaGrafica areaGrafica) {              // invoked at the beginning
        this.areaGrafica = areaGrafica;                         
    }

    /**
     * This method is called by the paintComponent() of the panel.
     * HERE THE SYNCHRONIZED MODIFIER IS NEEDED: IF I REMOVE IT, I GET java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     */
    synchronized void redrawAll(Graphics g) {
        final Iterator<Stone> iter = set.iterator();
        Stone stone;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            stone = iter.next();
            g.setColor(stone.getColor());
            g.fillOval(stone.getX(), stone.getY(), stone.getSize(), stone.getSize());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks the GUI's Fire button (actionPerformed awt event).
     */
    void addGoodStone() {
        Stone stone = new GoodStone();              // GoodStone is a Stone
        addStone(stone);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks the GUI's Killer button (actionPerformed awt event).
     */
    void addKillerStone() {
        Stone stone = new KillerStone();            // KillerStone is a Stone
        addStone(stone);
    }

    /**
     * This method adds a stone into the set, so it modifies the set, but...
     * ...HERE I REMOVED THE SYNCHRONIZED MODIFIER AND I NEVER GOT ANY EXCEPTION.
     */
    private void addStone(Stone stone) {
        stone.start();                              // start the thread (each stone is a thread)
        set.add(stone);                             // put the stone into the set
        System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks a point on the panel (mouseClicked awt event).
     * This method removes more than one of the stones from the set, but...
     * ...HERE I REMOVED THE SYNCHRONIZED MODIFIER AND I NEVER GOT ANY EXCEPTION.
     */
    void killStone(int xClicked, int yClicked) {
        final Iterator<Stone> iter = set.iterator();
        Stone stone;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            stone = iter.next();

            if (SOME CONDITIONS, READING THE STONE STATUS) {
                stone.interrupt();                      // stop the thread
                iter.remove();                          // remove the stone from the set
                System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
            }
        }

        if (set.isEmpty()) {
            areaGrafica.repaint();                      // remove the image of the final stone from the panel
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method is called by the run() method of the killer stones (see later).
     * HERE THE SYNCHRONIZED MODIFIER IS NEEDED: IF I REMOVE IT, I GET java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     */
    synchronized void killNeighbouringGoodStones(int x, int y, int radius) {
        final Iterator<Stone> iter = set.iterator();
        Stone stone;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            stone = iter.next();

            if (SOME OTHER CONDITIONS, USING THE STONE STATUS) {
                stone.interrupt();                      // stone is a thread
                iter.remove();                          // remove the stone from the set
                System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
/**
 * This is the run() method of the Stone class.
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    try {                                   // while into the try
        while (true) {
            animate();                      // this simple method changes the stone state (*)
            Stone.areaGrafica.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP);            // SLEEP is 50 ms
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

(*) if the stone is a killer stone, the animate() method is overridden:
@Override
void animate() {
    super.animate();
    set.killNeighbouringGoodStones(getCenterX(), getCenterY(), getSize() / 2);      // here set is the singleton StoneSet
}
```

---

```
/**
 * This is the paintComponent() method of the panel.
 */
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);                    
    set.redrawAll(g);
}
```

I thought the `synchronized` modifier was mandatory for all methods that access a shared object, but apparently this is not true.

EDIT

I had an idea: maybe...

- ...redrawAll() and killNeighbouringGoodStones() need the synchronized modifier because those methods are called by other threads I created, while...
- ...addStone() and killStone() may not be synchronized because those methods are called by GUI-enabled API listeners.

Could it be true?

Comment: Just because your code doesn't use `synchronized` that doen't mean that you automatically see error immediately.  Thread error are often intermittent and don't show up until a heavy load is present.  They could show up at any time however, that's what intermittent means.

Comment: So, your opinion is to mark as synchronized all the methods that change the shared object? So it doesn't matter which thread runs each of them?

Comment: It depends on how you call the non-`synchronized` methods. If you call them from another method that _is_ `synchronized` then you may be okay (assuming the state is guarded by the same monitor).

Comment: FYI: Some time around 1981 or 1982, I implemented a bouncing balls demo using a single thread running on a [minicomputer workstation with about a 6 MHz clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ). My program smoothly animated more than 20 balls at 30 fps frame rate, _and_ it tested for collisions between them. With modern CPUs running several hundreds of times faster, I'm wondering what is your reason for dedicating a separate thread for each moving object?

Comment: It's important to note that ConcurrentModificationException does not necessarily indicate a thread safety problem -- it's extremely common to get a ConcurrentModificationException with only single-threaded code. (See [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636).) And the absence of a ConcurrentModificationException *definitely* does not mean the code is thread safe! Thread safety is difficult because thread-unsafe code will still usually do the right thing more often than the wrong thing, even when the code is incorrect.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you're right: but I wanted to try a multithreading approach to show a multithreaded graphical application to my pupils.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a world of difference between: "I am not getting exceptions", "the code is correct" and "the code, as currently deployed, works correctly".
2. If a mutable object is protected by a synchronized block, EVERY access to that object MUST be protected by a block synchronized on the SAME monitor. Otherwise the code is not thread safe and bad things can happen (and this goes both for reading and for writing).
3. If a code is not thread safe, it might work well enough, especially, if you are writing a game, not a banking system. The really tough errors could appear only under specific circumstances: one in billion executions, on some specific version of JVM, when some additional condition is true etc.
4. **The exceptions you are getting are probably not typical threading errors**: they come from the fact that `HashSet` is a fail-fast collection and you are not allowed to remove elements from it using different iterators at the same time. To put it in different words: even if you synchronized the `HashSet` itself, you would still get this error, even though - from pure thread safety perspective - the code would be correct.
5. As Solomon Slow already commented, your design is not really suited for using threads. So I assume you are doing this for fun / to learn Java threading. It is then especially important to do things correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

You use sychronized if multiple threads try to change the same object at the same time. As you noticed if remove synchronized from some of you methods you get an exception, because all of them try to modify the HashSet at the same time.

You must ensure that the following things to not happen at the same time (triggered by two different Threads):

```
1. Iteration over the values in the the HashSet
2. Modification of the Data inside the HashSet
```

From a codestyle point of view, synchronized is never 'mandatory'. Its up to the developer to figure out where to use it, so that your code works correctly.

You also want to take a look at the 'volatile' keyword to ensure that all threads see the same content.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to make by saying "From a codestyle point of view, synchronized is never 'mandatory'." What does that mean? I guess you could say having code that compiles, or code that runs without deleting all your files, or anything else, is never "mandatory" either, but that doesn't seem to be a meaningful statement. And incorrect synchronization doesn't just mean you might get bad data values *inside* the data structure. You can (and will!) also [corrupt the data structure itself](https://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html).

Comment: I'd guess "codestyle...never mandatory" might mean that you're not going to have an automatic style checker tell you where you need sync, you're going to have to figure it out yourself. Maybe.

Comment: What 'another-dave' said, or even simpler you're not gonna see any compiler warnings. The wording of 'geko' made it look to me like he exepects that something will enforce this and that any 'shared' code that is not sychnronized will not work. But there are certainly conditions where the data corruption is less important - as long as the data remains usable and certain other conditions are met - than the time that would be wasted waiting for the synchronisation.