# Getting Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java, bukkit, concurrentmodification

I have no idea why I'm getting this error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiYXz.png)

This is line 107 (for loop):

```
        for (Pair<UUID, UUID> pair : timeStopList) {

           if (pair.getA() == playerUUID) {

              cancelTimeStop(pair.getB());

           }

        }
```

I hate to ask what might seem like such a simple solution but I really have no idea whats going on! So I would appreciate it that if you know the answer you could tell me. Thanks!

Code for cancelTimeStop:

```
    public static void cancelTimeStop(UUID entityUUID) {

    Entity unknownEntity = Bukkit.getEntity(entityUUID);

    if (unknownEntity == null || unknownEntity.isDead()) return;

    LivingEntity entity = (LivingEntity) unknownEntity;

    entity.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW);
    entity.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS);

    entity.setGravity(true);
    entity.setAI(true);
    entity.setCanPickupItems(true);
    entity.setSilent(false);

    removeEntityFromTimeStop(entityUUID);

}
```

removeEntityFromTimeStop() is:

```
    private static void removeEntityFromTimeStop(UUID entityUUID) {

    if (timeStopList == null) return;

    timeStopList.removeIf(pair -> pair.getB() == entityUUID);

}
```

Comment: A `ConcurrentModificationException` means you're altering a data structure (here - a `List`) while iterating over it. Can you share the code for `cancelTimeStop`?

Comment: @Mureinik `        Entity unknownEntity = Bukkit.getEntity(entityUUID);

        if (unknownEntity == null || unknownEntity.isDead()) return;

        LivingEntity entity = (LivingEntity) unknownEntity;

        entity.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW);
        entity.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS);

        entity.setGravity(true);
        entity.setAI(true);
        entity.setCanPickupItems(true);
        entity.setSilent(false);

        removeEntityFromTimeStop(entityUUID);`

Comment: It's really hard to understand code posted in comments like this. Please [edit] your post and add this as formatted text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-and-how-to-debug-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change slightly your `for loop` to avoid this exception:

```
Pair<UUID, UUID> pairToRemove = null;
for (Pair<UUID, UUID> pair : timeStopList) {
    if (pair.getA() == playerUUID) {
        pairToRemove = pair; // assign the found pair to pairToRemove variable
        break;
    }
}
if (pairToRemove != null) {
    cancelTimeStop(pairToRemove.getB());
}
```

**UPDATE**

P.S. I made the assumption that once a `pair.getA() == playerUUID` is found there is no need to continue the loop. If there are multiple chances that this if statement evaluates to `true` then you can adjust the code to:

```
List<Pair<UUID, UUID>> pairToRemoveList = new ArrayList();
for (Pair<UUID, UUID> pair : timeStopList) {
    if (pair.getA() == playerUUID) {
        pairToRemoveList.add(pair);
    }
}
if (!pairToRemoveList.isEmpty()) {
    for (Pair<UUID, UUID> pair : pairToRemoveList) {
        cancelTimeStop(pair.getB());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent Modification Exception is thrown when iterating a collection and an item is removed from it. In this case a `Pair<UUID, UUID>` is removed from the `timeStopList`

```
timeStopList.removeIf(pair -> pair.getB() == entityUUID);
```

The solution is to use Iterator when you have to remove the list while iterating and no other modification is needed to your logic:

```
Iterator<Pair<UUID, UUID>> iter = cancelTimeStop.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(...){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```