# Putting into HashMap at 0 index is causing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections

I have a simple `HashMap` algorithm:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 1);
map.put(2, 2);
map.put(3, 3);

Iterator<Integer> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer key = it.next();
    if (key.equals(2)) {
        map.put(1, 2);
    }
}
```

and this is working fine. **But** when I will modify the condition body to:

```
if (key.equals(2)) {
    map.put(0, 2); // changed index '1' to '0'
}
```

it's always throwing `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. The same is happening for key values lesser than `0`.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit**

Seems that if I will remove the third `Map` element:

```
map.put(1, 1);
map.put(2, 2);
// map.put(3, 3);
```

it's working fine

Comment: A `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs when you modify a collection you are currently iterating over. The iterator is not being notified of the change on the underlying collection. Create a copy of the collection to iterate over, to avoid this. The first one is working fine, since you don't change the size of the collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-and-how-to-debug-it)

Comment: but `map.put(1, 2);` is working fine - I would understand if the exception would be thrown everytime but why it's happening only for `<=0` keys?

Comment: put(100000,x) will do the same

Comment: In this particular implementation of hasmap iterator, size of the collection is what matters, not actual key-value pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the size of the map during iteration which causes the exception. Keep in mind that it is not `put` operation that throws the exception but an attempt to get next element via iterator via `Iterator#next`

In your case, if you have "extended" the map, iterator will throw exception on `next()`. However if it was done on the last iteration, `hasNext` returns false. This will lead to skipping `next()` call and will not throw an exception.

Comment: so why `map.put(1, 2);` is working fine?

Comment: Because you are not changing the size of the map. YOu start with X elements and after put its still X elements - you replaced existing key with new value. put (0,x) adds new element thus changing size of the map. Any other `put(notYetInTheMap,x)` will cause this as well as removal of the element

Comment: this makes sense but then why is this working when I have elements at `1` and `2` and then do `map.put(0, 2)`? (please see my edit)

Comment: Again, you replace element and the map is still of size 2. **Map size is what matters here** not its content

Comment: I do not - I don't have element with `key = 0`

Comment: @m.antkowicz then it's fine, since it's the last iteration of the iterator anyways, there is no more `hasNext()` checks.

Comment: I'm so sorry @Antioniossss I missed button in the comment - I meant `map.put(0,2)`

Comment: As I wrote, exception is thrown by the iterator during next() call, so no call == no exception.

Comment: Ok guys you are right! It's because it was the last run of the `while` loop - when I'm changing condition to `if(key.equals(1))` I have again the exception. Thank you so much I was going crazy!

Answer (score 1):

It's not related only for keys lesser than 0.

First of all it works with **map.put(1, 2);** because here you not add new item to map, you just replace existing value to another.

But if you try to add any new item with new index (such as 0 in your example, but there can be any new index, for example 4,5,6,....) you always get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.

So you **can't** add new items inside the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) (emphasis added):

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: **if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException**. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

*Structural modification* is defined earlier as:

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.

So:

- `map.put(1, 2);` is not a structural modification, because the key `1` is already in the map. All you are doing is changing the value it is associated with. No `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.
- `map.put(0, 2);` **is** a structural modification, because the key `0` is not already in the map. As such, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.