# ConcurrentModificationException on a object wrapped with lock

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, locking, concurrentmodificationexception

I've left my application up for a night and noticed such a stacktrace in the morning:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:756) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:788) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:786) ~[na:na]
    at ****.MyClass.cleanup(MyClass.kt:150) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I tried to find a root cause but I was not able to.  So let me provide simplified version of my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConnectionProperties::class)
class MyClass(
    private val myProperties: MyConnectionProperties,
) {

    private val logger: KLogger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
    private val myLock = ReentrantLock()
    private val myHolder: MutableMap<String, MyConnectionExtension> = mutableMapOf()
     
    @Scheduled(cron = "...")
    fun cleanup() {
        val connectionsToClose: MutableList<LDAPConnection> = mutableListOf()

        myLock.withLock {
            myHolder.forEach { (userDn, connectionExtension) ->
                val lastTouchTime = max(
                    connectionExtension.connection.lastCommunicationTime,
                    connectionExtension.lastPullingTime,
                )
                val connectionName = connectionExtension.connection.connectionName

                

                if (lastTouchTime + ldapConnectionProperties.lifetimeMs < Instant.now().toEpochMilli()) {
                    myHolder.remove(userDn)
                    connectionsToClose.add(connectionExtension.connection)

                   
                }
            }
        }

        connectionsToClose.forEach { connection ->
            try {
                connection.close()               
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.warn(e) {"....."}
            }
        }

        logger.trace { "job finished" }
    }
    
    private fun getConnection(userId: String, password: String): LDAPConnection {
        myHolder.withLock {
            val connectionExtension = connectionHolder[userId]
            val connection = connectionExtension?.connection

            return if (connection == null || !connection.isConnected) {
                createConnection(userId, password).also {
                    connectionHolder[userId] = LdapConnectionExtension(
                        connection = it,
                        lastPullingTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(),
                    )
                }
            } else {                
                connectionExtension.lastPullingTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
                connection
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

There are only 2 functions which use `myHolder` so I provided only them. From my point of view access to `myHolder` is covered with lock so no concurrent issue is expected even although map is not concurrent here.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: I think its might not be due to multithreading/concurrency issue, but it could be due to removal of the element incorrectly? I m not too familiar with kotlin, but it looks like you are directly removing from the Map itself, but the foreach is using an iterator internally. Thus the iterator will throw the concurrent exception because you are modifying the map concurrently while the iterator is iterating https://stackoverflow.com/a/602660/16034206

Comment: You can't call myHolder.remove() inside a myHolder.forEach(). You should rather add all which you want to remove to a temporary collection and remove them afterwards all at once.

Comment: certainly asked before (for Java) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10431981/85421), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223918/85421), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76941832/85421), ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments said, you are `remove`ing from a map, while iterating over it with `forEach`. `forEach` spins up an iterator, if you change the map while iterating over it, a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown.

Solution would be to record all elements you want to remove in a separate collection, then go over those after the forEach iteration and remove them from the map.

Comment: Thank you ! I knew it but looks like I became blind

Comment: Or use an `Iterator` directly and [use the iterator’s `remove()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()).